# Desempenho na criação de strings em Java

Tags: java, string, desempenho

Qual é a melhor forma de se criar strings em Java de modo a se obter um melhor desempenho? Seguem dois exemplos de criação de strings em Java:

**Ex. 1:**

```
String str = "string";
```

**Ex. 2:**

```
String str = new String("string");
```

Comment: Não sou nenhuma autoridade em Java para falar sobre isso, mas acredito que na versão atual do Framework, ambas as formas podem ser equivalentes (a supor que haja internalização).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A resposta do @QMechanic73 é boa, entretanto ela me levantou uma dúvida que eu acabei de pesquisar para entender. Por que no exemplo `a==c` e `b==c` sempre retornam `false`?

```
String a = new String("foo");
String b = new String("foo");
String c = "foo";

System.out.println(a == c); // False
System.out.println(b == c); // False
```

Para complementar a resposta dele, quando você cria uma *String* com o operador `new` você está criando um objeto para essa *String* no `heap` e quando cria a *String* sem o `new` você está buscando uma *String* na `pool de Strings`, entretanto se não tiver nenhuma *String* na `pool` uma nova *String* é criada, **independente de já existir ou não uma *String* idêntica no *heap*.**

Por isso somente na comparação das duas *Strings* criadas sem o operador `new` retorna *true*.

Um exemplo retirado [desse site aqui.](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j3d_string.html)

Ao fazer isso:

```
String s1 = "Hello";              // String literal
String s2 = "Hello";              // String literal
String s3 = s1;                   // mesma referência
String s4 = new String("Hello");  // objeto String 
String s5 = new String("Hello");  // objeto String
```

Se tem isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem que caso o `s4` e o `s5` tivessem sido criados antes do `s1`, `s2` e `s3` o diagrama não sofreria alteração, seria o mesmo que o acima.

Respondendo sua pergunta, a melhor forma de criar *Strings* é sem o operador `new`, pois as chances de reutilizar *String* são maiores, já que toda vez que você precisar de uma *String* e ela já existir não será necessário criar outra.

Answer (score 17):

No primeiro caso é sempre o mesmo objeto sendo recuperado da [String Constant Pool](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/19/the-string-constant-pool/) no segundo caso, um **novo** objeto está sendo criado.

```
String str = new String("foo");
```

Você obriga a criação de um novo objeto *String* e isso consome um pouco de tempo e memória.

```
String str = "foo";
```

`str` só será criado pela primeira vez (*um novo objeto*), e será armazenada em cache na [String Constant pool](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/19/the-string-constant-pool/), por isso cada vez que você se referir a ele em sua forma literal, você está recebendo exatamente o mesmo objeto, o que é bastante rápido.

```
String str = "foo";
```

A [JVM](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_virtual_Java) realiza alguns truques enquanto instanciar *strings literais/objetos* para aumentar o desempenho e diminuir a sobrecarga de memória. Para reduzir o número de objetos *String* criados, A *JVM* mantém uma memória especial chamada *String constant pool*. Cada vez que criado uma string literal, a JVM verifica a *String constant pool* primeiro.

Se a string já existe na *String Pool*, uma referência para a instância é retornado. Se a string não existe, um novo objeto *String* é criado e colocado na Pool. A *JVM* mantém no máximo um objeto de qualquer *String* na Pool. *Strings* literais sempre se referem a um objeto na *String Pool*.

### Como Funciona?

A JVM verifica a [String Constant Pool](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/19/the-string-constant-pool/) primeiro, e se a string não existir, é criado um novo objeto String `foo` e uma referência é mantida na Pool. A variável `str` também se refere ao mesmo objeto.

E se tivermos uma declaração como essa?

```
String str2 = "foo";
```

A [JVM](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_virtual_Java) verifica a *String Constant Pool* e uma vez que a string **já existe**, uma referência para a instância é devolvida a `str2`. Essa declaração não cria qualquer objeto *String* na memória e `str2` refere-se o mesmo objeto como `str`.

Para verificar isso, você pode comparar duas referências *String* utilizando o operador [`==`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)(veja também [**Como comparar Strings em Java?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java)) para verificar se duas referências se referem ao mesmo objeto *String* na memória.

```
String str = new String("foo");
String str2 = new String("foo");
String str3 = "foo";
String str4 = "foo";

System.out.println(str == str2);   // false
System.out.println(str == str3);   // false
System.out.println(str3 == str4);  // true
```

### [Ideone](https://ideone.com/dbFEaK)

`str3` e `str4` são o mesmo objeto logo, a comparação [`==`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) é verdadeira.

Ilustração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Referências

1. [new String() vs literal string performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14758013/1608936)
2. [String Literal Pool](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/strings/string-literal-pool/)

Comment: Apenas acrescentando: caso você precise criar novas instâncias de String, por exemplo, para representar textualmente entradas numéricas do usuário (`String.valueOf(qtdInformada)`), você pode economizar memória ao armazenar a referência retornada pelo método "`.intern()`" da String que você acabou de criar. Isso fará com que sua string seja adicionada ou recuperada do Pool. **Lembre-se** de atribuir o retorno do método à variável que armazenava sua String criada, senão serão dois objetos em memória ao invés de um!