# Orientação a Objetos em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Sou novato em `Java` e gostaria de entender como ela funciona.
Tipo, como uso `classe` dentro da outra (e como se chama)?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Por exemplo: ele está enviando o `Bundle` no método mas ele não é uma `String` nem um `int` ou coisa parecida. Como isso funciona exatamente?

E outra. Quando criamos uma variável `String`, por exemplo:

```
String a = "aa";
```

Por que não precisamos usar o operador `new` e o que acontece se deixarmos de usá-lo em um objeto qualquer?

Comment: A segunda pergunta sua está respondida aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19098/3117 . Tente sempre manter apenas uma pergunta por tópico, se o link que eu lhe passei responder a sua dúvida você pode retirá-la editando sua pergunta.

Comment: A sua primeira pergunta está confusa. Você entende como funcionam os métodos? Pois bem, o parâmetro nesse caso é um objeto do tipo Bundle, ao invés de ser um `int` ou uma String. O que você quer saber como funciona nisso?

Comment: Sim.. É isso que esta me deixando em duvida.. Por que não um int ou string mas sim um Bundle? Tipo ele não é um valor primitivo. Como isso funciona?

Comment: Nesse caso o que você quer entender então é como funcionam objetos? Você já criou uma classe alguma vez? Inicializou ela? Chamou métodos dela? Objetos são como os tipos primitivos, só que mais complexos, rs.. São como se fossem um aprimoramento do struct do C. Ah, e String em Java é uma classe,  não é primitivo assim como o `int` ou o `double`.

Comment: Então... Mas eu não entendo como q eu consigo usar isso em um método... Como eu vou manipular esse objeto sendo ele parâmetro de um método? Entende minha dúvida? :P

Comment: Na verdade não entendi não, rs.. Você usa ele dentro de um método assim como se você tivesse instanciado ele dentro do método, só que nesse caso ele foi instanciado em algum outro lugar. Assim como os primitivos, você pode criar um int novo dentro de um método, ou pode receber um por parâmetro.

Answer (score 2):

Amigão! 
Aqui o espaço é meio curto para lhe explicar tudo! 
Sugiro alguma apostila ( http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/ ).

Este método que você mostrou, pertence à um projeto Android, certo?
Então, quem cria uma instancia é o aplicativo.
Que ao inicializar o .xml da tela, manda este Bundle para o método!

Sobre a segunda pergunta: 
Quando se faz  `String a = "aa";` é o mesmo que   `String a = new String("aa");`, pois quando o compilador processar/ler o `""` entende se como `new String("");`

Comment: Concordo com @Thiago Luiz Domacoski. Procure uma boa apostila, curso, existem vários, se o inglês não é um problema pra você, de uma olhada no coursera, tem excelente cursos lá. Harvard vem também oferecendo cursos gratuitos pela internet. 


https://www.coursera.org/

Comment: obg mas tipo nao achei onde fala sobre isso.. Qual o nome que se da quando passamos um objeto como parâmetro de um método? (pra eu achar mais facil)

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas veja sobrecarga de método!

Comment: Tipo.. O onCreate(Bundle saveInstance) eu to passando como parâmetro um objeto não um valor primitivo como int ou char entende? **ex onCreate(int saveInstance)** Tipo eu qeria saber qal o nome disso pra eu poder me aprofundar mais nisso

Comment: A primeira pergunta dele não foi devidamente respondida, você só disse quem criou, mas não explicou como funciona. A resposta para a segunda pergunta está errada, inicializar uma string com new e sem new não são as mesmas coisas.

Comment: Oi, Thiago, [esta edição que você sugeriu](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/51645) não foi aprovada porque conflitou com uma minha. Estou dando um toque porque sua sugestão deixou de fora um bloco gigante de código que estava escondido... Vale a pena conferir este faq de vez em quando [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/201) ;)