# Formas de instanciar uma String em Java

Tags: java

Qual a diferença entre essas duas formas de instanciar uma String em Java?

```
String x = "y";

String x = new String("y");
```

Comment: Duplicada de [Desempenho na criação de strings em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19098/5878)

Answer (score 1):

Diferença básica é que o primeiro exemplo vai ficar no pool de string e o segundo na memoria de objeto.

Além disso usar o `String x = new String("y");` é mais lento que o outro método.

Confira esse link para entender o pool de strings [Desempenho na criação de strings em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19098/desempenho-na-cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-strings-em-java)