# Condição de IF é verdadeira mas não executa o código relacionado

Tags: java, android, if

Tenho o meu programa que exibe uma mensagem e nessa mesma mensagem o usuário deve digitar um código. Estou tentando fazer a validação se ele digitou algo ou não, para isso uso o código:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert.setTitle("Código final"); //Set Alert dialog title here
    alert.setMessage("Insira o código fornecido pela Nobre de la Torre:"); //Message here

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(context);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
     //Ações do botão da mensagem
     String srt = String.valueOf(input.getEditableText());
     if(srt!=""){ //ESSE É O IF QUE ESTÁ COM ERRO
     Toast.makeText(context,srt,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
     }
     else
     {
     Toast.makeText(context,"Campo vazio!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
     }  
      String hexNumber = srt;
      int decimal = Integer.parseInt(hexNumber, 16);
      System.out.println("Hex value is " + decimal); 
                 [COntinua...]
```

Mesmo com a variável `String srt` sendo `""` ele enxerga como diferente de `""` e executa o código abaixo dele

```
String srt = String.valueOf(input.getEditableText());
if(srt!=""){ 
    Toast.makeText(context,srt,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Sendo que ele deveria executar o `else` :

```
else {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Campo vazio!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java

Answer (score 3):

Modifique para esta implementação

```
String srt =input.getText().toString();
if(!srt.equals(""))
```

O metodo `getEditableText()` da classe `EditText` retorna um objeto do tipo `Editable`, para pegar o texto você deve utilizar o metodo `getText()` que retorna um objeto do tipo `CharSequence`, logo apos basta converte-lo para String.

Comment: coloquei como o seguinte: 
`String srt =input.getText().toString();
     if(srt.equals(""))
       {
           Toast.makeText(context,"Campo vazio!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
       }
     else
       {
            Toast.makeText(context,srt,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
       }  `  E agora parou a aplicação deu erro.

Comment: Qual erro? @kaamis

Comment: Só um adendo, coloquei uma negação no if pois percebi que a condição é diferente de Vazio certo.

Comment: Sua resposta de certo @TuyoshiVinicius mesmo sem a negação. O erro creio eu que seja pela continuidade do código. Ao sair do `if` existe uma variável `String` que recebe o valor de `srt`. Se ela for vazia dá erro na continuidade do código. Teria que ao entrar no `if` e verificar que `srt` é vazio ter a possibilidade de executar o código da condição e parar por lá. Para não dar continuidade no código até que `srt` seja diferente de vazia.