# Testar um construtor com mais de um parâmetro

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, junit

Estou tentando criar uma classe de testes para meu construtor, mas ele recebe três parâmetros e esses parâmetros são validados dentro da própria classe, para permitir ou não a criação da instância dele.

Segue código:

```
public class Mamiferos{
private String nome;
private Date dataNasc;
private String sexo;

public Mamiferos(String nome, Date dataNasc, String sexo){      
    try {

        validaSexo();
        validaNome();
        validaData();

        }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

        }finally{
            this.nome = nome;
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            try {
                this.dataNasc = format.parse(dataNasc.toString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.sexo =sexo;            
        }
}

private Boolean validaData() {

    Date dataAtual = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    if (dataNasc.before(dataAtual)){
        return true;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Por favor, digite uma data válida.\n");
        return false;
    }   
}

private Boolean validaNome() {

    if (nome.isEmpty() || nome.length()<5) {
        System.out.println("O nome deve ter ao menos 5 caracteres.\nDigite novamente.");
        return false;           
    }else{
        return true;        
    }       
}

private Boolean validaSexo() {

    if (sexo != "Male" || sexo != "Female" || sexo.isEmpty()) {

        System.out.println("O sexo não pode ser nulo.\nDigite o sexo (Male/Female).\n");
        return false;

    } else {
        return true;
    }       
}
```

Abaixo minha tentativa frustada de classe de teste:

```
public class NameTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
```

Sim, vazia, não sei como testar os validadores. Não queria deixá-los publicos pois não faz sentido.

PS: Aceito sugestões.

Obrigado!

Comment: Olá, não conheço esse Hibernate Validator. É necessário criar uma persistência para utilizá-lo?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente sua classe tem alguns problemas:

- Os métodos `validaData()`, `validaNome()` e `validaSexo()` retornam um `Boolean` indicando se a validação foi bem sucedida ou não. Entretanto, o seu construtor simplesmente ignora o valor retornado, e como resultado, ele aceita os parâmetros mesmo que estejam errados, o que equivale a não realizar validação nenhuma.
- Os métodos `validaData()`, `validaNome()` e `validaSexo()` olham para os valores dos campos da sua classe antes dos mesmos terem sido definidos, e portanto sempre enxergarão os valores `null` e sempre falharão a validação mesmo se a sua classe for instanciada corretamente.
- Se algum dos métodos `validaData()`, `validaNome()` ou `validaSexo()` lançasse alguma exceção, você apenas a ignoraria, e isto significa simplesmente ignorar qualquer problema de validação e aceitar qualquer coisa.
- Os métodos `validaData()`, `validaNome()` e `validaSexo()` nunca retornam `null` e nem estão usando `Boolean` como a especificação de algum tipo genérico covariante. Por este motivo, use `boolean` ao invés de `Boolean`. Ou então use o mecanismo de exceções de forma adequada e mude o tipo para `void`.
- Não há sentido definir os valores dos campos no bloco `finally` do construtor. Aliás, nem sequer faz sentido usar o `finally` aqui.

  Se o bloco `try` terminar com uma exceção, o código que invocou o construtor não poderá atribuir o resultado da chamada do construtor a nenhuma variável, e portanto a instância recém-criada será perdida. Ora, se a instância recém-criada será perdida, definir os valores de seus campos será uma atitude em vão.

  Por outro lado, se o bloco `try` terminar normalmente, o código do `finally` também será executado normalmente tal como se estivesse logo após o `try-catch`.

  Uma vez que o seu bloco `try` apenas come as exceções que são lançadas dentro dele, executar o `finally` seria equivalente a apenas seguir com o fluxo normal após o final do bloco `try-catch`, e neste caso o seu bloco `finally` é inútil.
- As mensagens de erro da validação são jogados fora no `System.out.println` e depois esquecidas para sempre. Não dá para utilizá-las após isso.
- Não vejo motivo de usar `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());` ao invés de simplesmente `new Date();`. Também acho mais simples definir a hora para meia-noite usando o `GregorianCalendar` ao invés de `SimpleDateFormat`, pois não há necessidade de tratar um `ParseException`.
- Se o construtor construir de fato o objeto, você vai precisar testar se ele construiu o objeto adequadamente. Por isso, alguns getters são necessários.
- Você está comparando `String`s usando `!=`. [Isso não vai fazer o que você quer.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/132) Além disso a sua validação sempre vai falhar porque `sexo != "Male" || sexo != "Female"` sempre vai ser verdadeiro, afinal o sexo sempre é diferente de macho ou fêmea, pois se for macho, então é diferente de fêmea (e portanto dá verdadeiro) e se for fêmea, então é diferente de macho (e também dá verdadeiro).

Não adianta tentar testar a validação de um construtor, se no final das contas ele efetivamente não consegue fazer validação nenhuma!

Vamos arrumar a sua classe. Vou usar `IllegalArgumentException` para representar um erro de validação. Vou fazer os métodos de validação validarem um parâmetro e o retornarem se este for aceito ou lançarem uma exceção se o rejeitarem. Também vou colocar a complexidade de jogar o `Date` para meia-noite (para retirar a hora) em um método a parte. A ideia é que o construtor lance uma exceção se receber parâmetros inválidos, o que significa que neste caso a instanciação do objeto é para todos os efeitos rejeitada.

```
public class Mamiferos {
    private String nome;
    private Date dataNasc;
    private String sexo;

    public Mamiferos(String nome, Date dataNasc, String sexo) {
        this.sexo = validaSexo();
        this.nome = validaNome();
        this.dataNasc = meiaNoite(validaData());
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public Date getDataNasc() {
        return dataNasc;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public static Date meiaNoite(Date data) {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTime(data);
        gc.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        gc.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        gc.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        gc.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return gc.getTime();
    }

    private static Date validaData(Date dataNasc) {
        Date dataAtual = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if (!dataNasc.before(dataAtual)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Por favor, digite uma data válida.");
        }
        return dataNasc;
    }

    private static String validaNome(String nome) {
        if (nome.isEmpty() || nome.length() < 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("O nome deve ter ao menos 5 caracteres.\nDigite novamente.");
        }
        return nome;
    }

    private static String validaSexo(String sexo) {
        if (!"Male".equals(sexo) && !"Female".equals(sexo)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("O sexo não pode ser diferente de Male/Female.");
        }
        return sexo;
    }
}
```

Agora vamos testar a sua classe:

```
public class TestMamiferos {

    private Date amanha() {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        return gc.getTime();
    }

    private Date ontem() {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        return gc.getTime();
    }

    @Test
    public void testInstanciaNormalmenteMale() {
        Date d = ontem();
        Mamiferos m = new Mamiferos("Gatinho", d, "Male");
        Assert.assertEquals("Gatinho", m.getNome());
        Assert.assertEquals(Mamiferos.meiaNoite(d), m.getDataNasc());
        Assert.assertEquals("Male", m.getSexo());
    }

    @Test
    public void testInstanciaNormalmenteFemale() {
        Date d = ontem();
        Mamiferos m = new Mamiferos("Gatinha", d, "Female");
        Assert.assertEquals("Gatinha", m.getNome());
        Assert.assertEquals(Mamiferos.meiaNoite(d), m.getDataNasc());
        Assert.assertEquals("Female", m.getSexo());
    }

    @Test
    public void testInstanciaNomeCurto() {
        try {
            new Mamiferos("A", ontem(), "Female");
            Assert.fail();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Assert.assertEquals("O nome deve ter ao menos 5 caracteres.\nDigite novamente.", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testInstanciaDataFuturo() {
        try {
            new Mamiferos("Gatinha", amanha(), "Female");
            Assert.fail();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Assert.assertEquals("Por favor, digite uma data válida.", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Outros testes
}
```

Enfim, este é o caminho dos testes. Nos testes que verificam o sucesso, o objeto é instanciado e o seu estado é verificado para certificar-se que o objeto foi devidamente inicializado pelo construtor. Nos testes que verificam as falhas, o `Assert.fail()` faz o teste falhar se o construtor **não** lançar uma exceção (uma vez que ele deveria lançar) e a exceção esperada é capturada e então é verificada se está correta (ou seja, que não se trata de alguma outra exceção diferente).

Recomendo testar todos os casos aonde uma exceção pode ser lançada, tal como o sexo inválido (que deixei de fora da classe de teste, este fica para você fazer). E aliás, há mais duas coisas que deixo para você resolver e aplicar os teste de unidade correspondentes:

- Se você passar `null` como parâmetros, ele deve rejeitar? O seu código apenas lança um `NullPointerException` que é imediatamente engolido neste caso. O meu código vai lançá-lo sem engulir. Altere o código para tratar isto e coloque um teste correspondente para cada caso aonde isso puder ocorrer.
- Você realmente deveria usar um `enum` para representar o sexo. Isso tornaria a sua vida bem mais fácil.

E por fim, recomendo estudar tratamento de exceções, você claramente não entende como ele funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão e o [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/).

O Hibernate Validator é uma implementação da especificão [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/).

O Bean Validation permite aplica regras de restrições em forma de anotação.

**Classe Mamifero usando Hibernate Validator:**

```
public class Mamifero {

@NotEmpty
@Length(min = 5)
private String nome;

@Past(message = "Por favor, digite uma data válida.")
private Calendar dataNasc;

@NotEmpty(message = "O sexo não pode ser nulo.")
@Pattern(regexp = "(Male|Female)", message = "Digite o sexo (Male/Female).")
private String sexo;

public Mamifero(String nome, Calendar dataNasc, String sexo) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.sexo = sexo;
    this.dataNasc = dataNasc;
  }
}
```

Para validar:

```
// Como é de costume nas especificações o método Factory
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();

// O validador
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

Calendar dataNasc = Calendar.getInstance(); 
dataNasc.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2003);
dataNasc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17);
dataNasc.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);

Mamifero mamifero = new Mamifero("Cachorro", dataNasc.getTime(), "Male");

// Valida e retorna uma lista Set com as restrições violadas como objeto ConstraintViolation
Set<ConstraintViolation<Mamifero>> violations = validator.validate(mamifero);
```

Para validar so uma propriedade do objeto:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Classe>> violations = validator.validateProperty(objeto, "propriedade");
```

A classe de teste:

```
public class MamiferoTest {

private Validator validator;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    this.validator = factory.getValidator();
}

@Test
public void testeArgumentoNomeSemNada() {
    Calendar dataNasc = Calendar.getInstance();

    dataNasc.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2003);
    dataNasc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17);
    dataNasc.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);

    Mamifero mamifero = new Mamifero("", dataNasc, "Male");

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Mamifero>> violations = validator.validate(mamifero);

    for (ConstraintViolation<Mamifero> violation : violations) {
        System.out.println(violation);
    }

    assertEquals(2, violations.size());
}

@Test
public void testeDataInvalida() {
    Calendar dataNasc = Calendar.getInstance();

    dataNasc.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
    dataNasc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17);
    dataNasc.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);

    Mamifero mamifero = new Mamifero("Cachorro", dataNasc, "Male");

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Mamifero>> violations = validator.validate(mamifero);

    for (ConstraintViolation<Mamifero> violation : violations) {
        System.out.println(violation);
    }

    assertEquals(1, violations.size());
}

@Test
public void testeSexoIncorreto() {
    Calendar dataNasc = Calendar.getInstance();

    dataNasc.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2003);
    dataNasc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17);
    dataNasc.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);

    Mamifero mamifero = new Mamifero("Cachorro", dataNasc, "Masculino");

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Mamifero>> violations = validator.validate(mamifero);

    for (ConstraintViolation<Mamifero> violation : violations) {
        System.out.println(violation);
    }

    assertEquals(1, violations.size());
  }
}
```

Para incluir em um projeto maven adiciona as seguintes dependências:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Hibernate Validator requer implementação do Unified Expression Language (EL):

```
<dependency> 
   <groupId> javax.el </groupId> 
   <artifactId> javax.el-api </artifactId> 
   <version> 2.2.4 </version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
   <groupId> org.glassfish.web </groupId> 
   <artifactId> javax.el </artifactId> 
   <version> 2.2.4 </version> 
</dependency>
```

Seu projeto não for maven baixa os jars no [site](http://hibernate.org/validator/).

Answer (score -1):

Você quer testar métodos privados de uma classe em um Test Unitário.

**Solução Número 1(o ideal é o approach da solução 2, esta é uma alternativa)**

Escreva seu Test como como uma membro público e estático da própria classe que tem seus métods privados.

Você vai precisar:

- transformar seus métodos de validação em métodos estáticos.
- criar uma classe pública como uma *static inner class*
- Passar os valores como parametros para esses métodos

  A vantagem desse approach é que é o mais simples e rápido, mas não melhor. Você terá um membro público que não tem coesão com a sua classe. E uma mistura de concerns diferentes em uma mesma classe. O ideal é ter seus testes bem separados.

**Solução Número 2**

Utilize Reflection para executar seus métodos privados em outros contextos.

Essa segunda solução funciona tanto para métodos státicos como para métodos não estáticos.

Reflection vai oferecer a você a opção de suprimir os checks de fields e métodos da JVM.

```
public void test()throws Exception{
    Class<?> clazz = Mamiferos.class;
    
    //vai precisar de um construtor publico sem argumento, ou acessar
    //seu contrutor privado, mudar acessibilidade dele e então instanciar
    //Ou apenas crie uma nova instancia de Mamifero
    //Mamifero m = new ....
    Object obj = clazz.newInstance();// = m;

    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("validaSexo");

    method.setAccesible(true);//Aqui está o segredo, ete método suprirá o modificador de acesso

    method.invoke();//Chamada ao seu método validaSexo
}
```

Como principal ponto negativo está o fato de você ter de excerver um código mais verboso, que o uso de Reflection em Java implica. Quanto a performance, apenas se você trabalhar em aplicações de ultra baixa latencia, isso será algo para se preoculpar. A JVM tem uma propriedade chamada Fast Reflection:

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html

Para ter um código mais legível e poderoso para operações reflectivas, considere usar a API Gren-Rfletea;

> https://github.com/FilipeGMiranda/GreenReflectea