# O comando if em java não esta funcionando dentro de um método

Tags: java, if

Sou iniciante e não estou conseguindo com que meu código funcione da maneira esperada com relação ao "if/else".

Estou utilizando esse comando dentro de um método e fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```java
private boolean AutentificaSenha(String s) {
    this.aSenha = s;
    boolean cond = this.senha == this.aSenha;
    if(cond) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

A minha intenção é criar um sistema de autenticação de dados para por em prática o que aprendi em algumas apostilas.

Esse método é um dos 3 métodos, após os 3 métodos privados há um último método público que chama os outros 3.

```java
public boolean Autentifica() {     
    System.out.println("Seu nome: ");
    this.aNome = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Sua senha: ");
    this.aSenha = entrada.nextLine();   
    System.out.println("Seu ID: ");
    this.aId = entrada.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Aguarde");
    boolean cond =
        this.AutentificaNome(this.aNome) &&
        this.AutentificaSenha(this.senha) &&
        this.AutentificaId(this.id);
    if (cond) {
        System.out.println("Logado com sucesso");
        return true;
    } else{
        System.out.println("Falha ao efetuar loguin");
        return false;
    }
}
```

O meu problema é que quando executo o código, sempre aparece "falha ao efetuar login" independente do que eu coloque.

P.S. as variáveis privadas: `nome`, `senha` e `id` já estão definidas.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como comparar Strings em Java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java)

Comment: O seu problema está no `this.senha == this.aSenha`. Isso não faz o que você espera que faria. Veja a questão do link no comentário acima.

Comment: É bem provável que seja isso mesmo, mas não dá pra ter certeza que seja só isso, sem ver os outros métodos. E Carlos, corrigindo o que o Victor apontou, veja que é possível simplificar o método postado para apenas uma linha: `return s.equals(this.senha);`.

Comment: Tome cuidado pois você está sobrescrevendo variáveis que não deveria (i.e. se você corrigir esse problema do `==` vs. `equals`, aí você vai ter o problema oposto: vai começar a dar "Logado com sucesso" mesmo se os dados estiverem errados). Por exemplo, na leitura você atribui `this.aSenha`, na hora de chamar a autenticação você usa `this.senha` (e não o que você acabou de ler) e dentro da autenticação você faz `this.aSenha = s` (`= this.senha`). Ou seja, no final das contas o teste vai dar verdadeiro sempre...

Comment: bfavaretto e @mgibsonbr, realmente, no `cond`, os campos são verificados de forma incoerente. Escrevi uma resposta detalhando tudo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Realmente há mais problemas do que apenas o `==`. Por isso, removi o meu voto de fechamento.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você não deu o código dos métodos `AutentificaNome` e `AutentificaId`, mas vou presumir que são análogos ao `AutentificaSenha`.

Assim, posso reconstruir a sua classe completa mais ou menos assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestaSenha {

    private Scanner entrada;
    private String senha;
    private String nome;
    private int id;
    private String aSenha;
    private String aNome;
    private int aId;

    public TestaSenha(Scanner entrada, String senha, String nome, int id) {
        this.entrada = entrada;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.id = id;
    }

    private boolean AutentificaNome(String s) {
        this.aNome = s;
        boolean cond = this.nome == this.aNome;
        if(cond) {
            return true;
        } else {
        return false; }
    }

    private boolean AutentificaSenha(String s) {
        this.aSenha = s;
        boolean cond = this.senha == this.aSenha;
        if(cond) {
            return true;
        } else {
        return false; }
    }

    private boolean AutentificaId(int s) {
        this.aId = s;
        boolean cond = this.id == this.aId;
        if(cond) {
            return true;
        } else {
        return false; }
    }

    public boolean Autentifica() {     
        System.out.println("Seu nome: ");
        this.aNome = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Sua senha: ");
        this.aSenha = entrada.nextLine();   
        System.out.println("Seu ID: ");
        this.aId = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Aguarde");
        boolean cond =
        this.AutentificaNome(this.aNome) &&
        this.AutentificaSenha(this.senha) &&
        this.AutentificaId(this.id);
        if (cond) {
            System.out.println("Logado com sucesso");
            return true;
        } else{
            System.out.println("Falha ao efetuar loguin");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

O seu erro mais grave é que comparar `String`s usando o operador `==` não vai fazer o que você quer. Você deveria usar o método `equals()`. O motivo é que o `==` compara se duas variáveis apontam para o mesmo objeto, o que vai dar errado quando você têm duas `String`s que embora tenham o mesmo conteúdo, são dois objetos diferentes. [Veja mais detalhes nesta pergunta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/132)

Ao fazer `str1.equals(str2)`, `true` será retornado se ambas as `String`s tiverem o mesmo conteúdo, e `false` em caso contrário, exceto se `str1` for `null`, o que resultará em um `NullPointerException`. Neste caso, podemos usar o seguinte:

```
Objects.equals(str1, str2);
```

E não se esqueça de adicionar o `import` necessário:

```
import java.util.Objects;
```

Assim, eis como fica o seu código:

```
private boolean AutentificaSenha(String s) {
    this.aSenha = s;
    boolean cond = Objects.equals(this.senha, this.aSenha);
    if(cond) {
        return true;
    } else {
    return false; }
}
```

E o mesmo vale para o `AutentificaNome`, mas não para o `AutentificaId` (pois `int`s não são objetos, então pode comparar com o `==` sem problema).

Podemos melhorar o seu código um pouco mais, afinal se a `cond` for verdadeiro, será retornado verdadeiro, e se `cond` for falso, será retornado falso. Que tal então retornar o `cond` diretamente então?

```
private boolean AutentificaSenha(String s) {
    this.aSenha = s;
    boolean cond = Objects.equals(this.senha, this.aSenha);
    return cond;
}
```

Estamos retornando `cond`, cujo valor sempre é o resultado de `Objects.equals(this.senha, this.aSenha)`. Então, podemos simplificar ainda mais ao retornar diretamente o resultado de `Objects.equals(this.senha, this.aSenha)`:

```
private boolean AutentificaSenha(String s) {
    this.aSenha = s;
    return Objects.equals(this.senha, this.aSenha);
}
```

E as regras de nomenclaturas do Java ditam que nomes de métodos devem iniciar com letras minúsculas. Assim, vamos colocar todos os seus quatro métodos com nomes iniciando com letras minúsculas.

Podemos fazer algo parecido no seu final do seu método principal também:

```
public boolean autentifica() {
    System.out.println("Seu nome: ");
    this.aNome = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Sua senha: ");
    this.aSenha = entrada.nextLine();   
    System.out.println("Seu ID: ");
    this.aId = entrada.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Aguarde");
    boolean cond =
            this.autentificaNome(this.aNome) &&
            this.autentificaSenha(this.senha) &&
            this.autentificaId(this.id);
    if (cond) {
        System.out.println("Logado com sucesso");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Falha ao efetuar login");
    }
    return cond;
}
```

Já que estamos olhando o seu método principal, já aproveitei e arrumei a grafia do "loguin" para "login" e também dei uma identada melhor na definição da variável `cond`. Aliás, vamos analisar esta variável melhor:

```
    boolean cond =
            this.autentificaNome(this.aNome) &&
            this.autentificaSenha(this.senha) &&
            this.autentificaId(this.id);
```

- Você lê as variáveis `aNome`, `aSenha` e `aId` do usuário, mas passa para os métodos as variáveis `aNome`, `senha` e `id`. Observe a incoerência entre as variáveis usadas.
- No método `autentificaNome`, o valor do `aNome` será atribuído ao próprio `aNome` (o que não faz nada) e então comparado com `nome`.
- No método `autentificaSenha`, o valor do `senha` será atribuído ao `aSenha`, ignorando o que o usuário digitou e fazendo as duas senhas serem sempre iguais.
- Com o método `autentificaId`, acontece algo semelhante ao `autentificaSenha`.

Agora chegamos em um ponto importante, o `aNome`, `aSenha` e `aId` são importantes de permanacerem gravados após o teste do login ser efetuado? Supondo que não, então o ideal seria você eliminar elas e usar apenas variáveis locais ao método `autentifica()`. Também não há necessidade de alterar o valor dos campos do objeto quando você está apenas testando se a senha digitada está correta ou não, afinal de contas uma tentativa de login, seja bem-sucedida ou não, não deveria alterar o login e a senha ou algo assim.

Desta forma, este é o seu código agora:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Objects;

public class TestaSenha {

    private Scanner entrada;
    private String senha;
    private String nome;
    private int id;

    public TestaSenha(Scanner entrada, String senha, String nome, int id) {
        this.entrada = entrada;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.id = id;
    }

    private boolean autentificaNome(String s) {
        return Objects.equals(this.nome, s);
    }

    private boolean autentificaSenha(String s) {
        return Objects.equals(this.senha, s);
    }

    private boolean autentificaId(int s) {
        return this.id == s;
    }

    public boolean autentifica() {     
        System.out.println("Seu nome: ");
        String aNome = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Sua senha: ");
        String aSenha = entrada.nextLine();   
        System.out.println("Seu ID: ");
        int aId = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Aguarde");
        boolean cond =
                this.autentificaNome(aNome) &&
                this.autentificaSenha(aSenha) &&
                this.autentificaId(aId);
        if (cond) {
            System.out.println("Logado com sucesso");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Falha ao efetuar login");
        }
        return cond;
    }
}
```

Sua classe já deverá estar funcionando adequadamente agora. O único detalhe é que fica mais fácil encapsulando a verificação das três condições juntas em um método próprio, e portanto o seu código fica assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Objects;

public class TestaSenha {

    private Scanner entrada;
    private String senha;
    private String nome;
    private int id;

    public TestaSenha(Scanner entrada, String senha, String nome, int id) {
        this.entrada = entrada;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.id = id;
    }

    private boolean autentificaNome(String s) {
        return Objects.equals(this.nome, s);
    }

    private boolean autentificaSenha(String s) {
        return Objects.equals(this.senha, s);
    }

    private boolean autentificaId(int s) {
        return this.id == s;
    }

    private boolean autentifica(String n, String s, int i) {
        return this.autentificaNome(n) &&
               this.autentificaSenha(s) &&
               this.autentificaId(i);
    }

    public boolean autentifica() {     
        System.out.println("Seu nome: ");
        String aNome = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Sua senha: ");
        String aSenha = entrada.nextLine();   
        System.out.println("Seu ID: ");
        int aId = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Aguarde");
        boolean cond = this.autentifica(aNome, aSenha, aId);
        if (cond) {
            System.out.println("Logado com sucesso");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Falha ao efetuar login");
        }
        return cond;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah sim, é que eu comecei a ler e tu tava respondendo no começo já como se fosse uma resposta.. dai comentei antes de terminar só pra ir "ganhando tempo"

Comment: Uau, você me deu uma aula. Eu realmente estava muito distraído fazendo isso acabei confundindo as variáveis que ia usar e não consegui acompanhar minha própria linha de raciocínio. Inclusive o mico de escrever "loguin". De toda forma você solucionou minha duvida e me mostrou como poderia ser mais fácil. Obrigado, vou prestar mais atenção da próxima vez.

Answer (score 4):

Resposta simples:

Strings em Java são objetos e cada um tem uma referência (endereço de memória) diferente, por exemplo `this.senha` e  `this.aSenha` portanto testando as refências via operador `==` sempre retornará falso. Nestes casos use sempre o método equals.

```
boolean cond = this.senha != null && this.senha.equals(this.aSenha);
```

Estou supondo que você queira garantir que foi informado alguma senha.

That's all !