# spinner alterar imagem causa erro: Out of Memory on a byte allocation

Tags: java, android

Tenho um spinner normal funcionando perfeito e tenho o seguinte código :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public ImageView img;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.add("A");
        adapter.add("B");
       
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgFundo);

    }

    

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        
        String escolhido = adapter.getItem(position);
        if(escolhido == "A") {

            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.imga);
            Toast.makeText(this, "entrou no if ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        
    }
}
```

Obs : As imagens estão em png
Porem esse código não esta funcionando...

> LOGCAT : 15:02:00.790 22578-22578/ A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 22578
>
> 11-05 10:07:44.042 17694-17694/ E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 9288016-byte allocation.

Ele nao troca como o requerido. Como posso arrumar?

Comment: Boa noite Augusto, aonde esta o Logcat? Pode ser despejo de memória.

Comment: GuilhermeNascimento  antes acreditava que o problema era erro pois a img era grande, porem ao analisar o logcat vi que era erro de memoria 11-05 10:07:44.042 17694-17694/ E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 9288016-byte allocation. Como posso arrumar ?

Comment: Como suspeitei despejo de memória, vou formular uma resposta, acho que vi o mesmo problema em algum lugar, já retorno.

Comment: ok obg  fico no aguardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei bem se este o problema, mas conforme esta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17213503/1518921):

Este erro `Out of memory on a 9288016-byte allocation` que dizer que houve um vazamento de memoria. Você está tentando alocar ~8MB de memória, e você não tem que muito memória suficiente disponível.

É provavel que você esteja tentando carregar um resource maior que ~8mb,
e neste caso pode ser um resource. ~8MB seria uma imagem verdadeiramente enorme.

Eu recomendaria que você descobrir quais recursos `drawable` são estes, em seguida reduzir o seu tamanho e os tamanhos de imagens similares.

Quando digo "tamanho" quero dizer em pixels e não o tamanho em disco, como o que importa é o tamanho descomprimido na RAM e não quão grande a imagem está no disco.

Além disso, este pode ser um problema de diretórios dos "resources". Por exemplo, se você colocar a sua imagem de `1200x1200` na pasta `res/drawable/`, quando o corretor deveria ser `res/drawable-mdpi/`.

Se este dispositivo passa a ser um dispositivo `-xhdpi`, então isso explicaria o uso de memória.

Você deve adicionar as imagens de por densidade em suas respectivas pastas:

- ldpi (low) ~120dpi
- mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
- hdpi (high) ~240dpi
- xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
- xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
- xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Supondo que a sua imagem tenha 480dpi aproximadamente, então ele deve ir nesta pasta por exemplo:

- `res/drawable-xxhdpi/`

Pra cada nova densidade que necessitar, será necessário criar uma pasta assim `res/drawable-[densidade]/` (trocando o `[densidade]` pela quantidade de dpi que a imagem tem).

<sub>Fonte: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html</sub>

Comment: amigo tem razão, diminui os px e funcionou estou com 458 × 1000 , qual o maximo que posso usar ?

Comment: Vai depender da pasta de resource que colocou, vou editar a pergunta @AugustoFurlan assim que possivel e coloco estes detalhes.

Comment: Ok , estou colocando todos dentro da drawable , como poderia colocar imagens boa ( mas quero abranger varios dispositivos ... )

Comment: @AugustoFurlan editei a reposta, veja se ajuda a entender.

Comment: estou vendo, muito obg , desculpa minha igonorancia, como vejo os dpis , pois hj so vejo px ...

Comment: Se for windows, clica com o direito do mouse na imagem, acho que nele fala os dpis da foto selecionada, não tenho certeza. @AugustoFurlan

Comment: ok obg me ajudou muito amigo

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
 if("A".equals(escolha)) {
            ImageView imgf = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            imgf.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_a);

   }
```

Quando se utiliza `==` comparamos se a referencia  é igual.

E quando utilizamos o equals, comparamos o valor !

para saber mais: [Como comparar Strings em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java)

Comment: Amigo, com o == ele entra no if, pois coloquei um toast para ver e exibiu que entrou no if, ele nao esta alterando  a imagem ....

Comment: ele executa mais não troca a imagem? no xml onde voce cria a imagem, tem alguma coisa setada no src?

Comment: Exatamente nao troca imagem ...

Comment: Nao , nao setei nd , coloco uma imagem com esse mesmo codigo no onCreate

Comment: Então tente usar a mesma instancia do onCreate. Crie a ImageView como uma variavel global !

Comment: Como define para var global ? Tentei usar a instancia do onecreate e também não funcionou ...

Comment: Crie o ImageView no escopo da classe, não dentro de algum método, então no onCreate você seta p valor dela: (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

Comment: Fiz isso , ainda nao deu certo ... Hahsha ta dificil...

Comment: Poste o q VC fez! Fica mais fácil de entender

Comment: Amigo, acabei de inserir o código completo

Comment: amigo ate coloquei o logcat