# Conferir campos de senha um com o outro

Tags: java

Como faço para validar dois campos de senha se ambos estão iguais?

```
if(pfSenha.getPassword() == pfCSenha.getPassword()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Senhas conferem!");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Senhas não conferem!");
}
```

Já tentei...

```
if(new String(pfSenha.getPassword()) == new String(pfCSenha.getPassword())) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Senhas conferem!");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Senhas não conferem!");
}
```

Como posso resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema do seu código é o operador `==`.

Em Java `==` compara se dois objetos apontam para a mesma referência (apenas para tipos não-primitivos, claro). No seu caso, deve-se usar o método `.equals()`

```
if(new String(pfSenha.getPassword()).equals(new String(pfCSenha.getPassword()))) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Senhas conferem!");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Senhas não conferem!");
}
```

---

Veja: [What's the difference between ".equals" and "=="?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1643067/4190610)
[Como comparar Strings em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/18246)

Comment: Falha minha. Edição aceita *=)*. Que bom que você conseguiu resolver

Comment: Eu? Você que me ajudou a resolver! Muito obrigado campeão!! Abraço!