# Comparando string digitada com a string no banco de dados

Tags: android

olá, estou fazendo um trabalho ... de um app em android em 3 camadas ... e é um app de avaliação de bares e lancherias ... que consiste em pegar o nome do local ... o endereco .. o email e a avaliaçao ... porem estou com uma dificuldade ... quero que ao pegar o local ele tenha que comparar se o local digitado ja é existente ao do banco de dados e nao deixar ele inserir novamente.

porem quando tento fazer isso ... meu metodo não da certo ... ele fecha ou insere normalmente ... o metodo é este

Essa é a libClass

```
public class Local {

    private int id;
    private String local;
    private String endereco;
    private String email;
    private String telefone;
    private Float avaliacao;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLocal() {
        return local;
    }

    public void setLocal(String local) {
        this.local = local;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public Float getAvaliacao() {
        return avaliacao;
    }

    public void setAvaliacao(Float avaliacao) {
        this.avaliacao = avaliacao;
    }
}
```

Esse é o metodo do botão que adiciona:

```
public void adicionar(View v) {

    if (editLocal.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

        editLocal.setError("Coloque um Local!");
    } else {
        if (editEndereco.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

            editEndereco.setError("Coloque um Endereço");
        } else {
            if (editTelefone.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                editTelefone.setError("Coloque um Telefone!");

            } else {

                Local local = new Local();

                local.setId(0);
                local.setLocal(editLocal.getText().toString());
                local.setEndereco(editEndereco.getText().toString());
                local.setEmail(editEmail.getText().toString());
                local.setTelefone(editTelefone.getText().toString());
                local.setAvaliacao(ratingBarNota.getRating());

                LocalBLL localBLL = new LocalBLL(getApplicationContext());

                Utilidades util = new Utilidades();

                //aqui começa a comparacao
                nomeLocal = editLocal.getText().toString();

                compara = localBLL.comparaLocais(nomeLocal);

                if (compara == 1) {

                    util.exibirToast(getApplicationContext(), "Local já Cadastrado!");

                } else {

                    try {

                        localBLL.insertLocal(local);
                        util.exibirToast(getApplicationContext(), "Você Salvou um Local!");

                        popularListView();
                        cancelar();

                    } catch(Exception ex) {

                        util.exibirToast(getApplicationContext(), getExternalCacheDir().toString());

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

E esse é o metodo da libBLL:

```
public int comparaLocais(String nomeLocal) {

    LocalDAL localDAL = new LocalDAL(context);

    Local local = null;

    return localDAL.comparaLocal(nomeLocal);

}
```

E esse é o metodo da libDAL:

```
public int comparaLocal(String nomeLocal) {

    String SELECT_LOCAISCOMPARACAO = "SELECT * from locais where nome_local ='" + nomeLocal + "'";

    BancoDados banco = new BancoDados(context);

    SQLiteDatabase db = banco.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_LOCAISCOMPARACAO, null);

    Local local = null;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        local = new Local();

        do {

            local.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            local.setLocal(cursor.getString(1));
            local.setEndereco(cursor.getString(2));
            local.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
            local.setTelefone(cursor.getString(4));
            local.setAvaliacao(cursor.getFloat(5));

        } while ( cursor . moveToNext ());

    }

    comparacao = local.getLocal();

    if (nomeLocal == comparacao) {

        return 1;

    } else {

        return 0;

    }

}
```

Ao meu ver ... era para estar funcionando ... sou iniciante em Android ... então se vocês puderem me ajudar agradeço muito ... estou quebrando a cabeça kk ao meu ver a variavel compara não recebe o valor de local.getlocal();

Agradeço se alguem souber desde já
O erro no logcat é esse do androidstudio é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Em Java o operador `==` não testa pela igualdade do conteúdo da `String`, ou seja, não é um teste da igualdade dos valores de cada string em si, mas sim um teste de igualdade das referências de cada variável (se referenciam, ou "apontam", para o mesmo endereço de memória).

- `==` : Testa por igualdade de referências
- `.equals()` : Testa por igualdade dos valores (ou conteúdo)

Mude para:

```
if (nomeLocal.equalsIgnoreCase(comparacao)) {
   return 1;
} else {
   return 0;
}
```

Utilizei o `equalsIgnoreCase()` porque imagino que seja sua intenção ignorar diferenças na caixa (maiúsculas vs minúscula).

Para deixar mais claro:

```
String str1 = "Loudenvier";
String str2 = str1;
String str3 = "Loudenvier";

str1 == str2; // (verdadeiro: são a mesma referência)
str1 == str3; // (falso: são referências diferentes (depende do otimizador))
str2 == str3; // (falso: idem)
str3.equals(str1); // (verdadeiro: têm o mesmo conteúdo)
str2.equals(str1); // (verdadeiro: têm o mesmo conteúdo, afinal ambas referenciam a mesma posição de memória)
```

**Explicação longa:**

Excluindo tipos primitivos, todas as demais variáveis em Java não guardam, em si, o valor, ou melhor, o conteúdo delas mesmas. Na verdade elas "apontam", ou referenciam seu próprio valor, que está guardado em outro local qualquer na memória. Em outras linguagens, normalmente de mais baixo nível (como C e C++), isso significa que as variáveis em Java são ponteiros (*pointers*) tipados. A sintaxe da linguagem torna trivial as operações "de ponteiros" (que geram tanta dor de cabeça em outras linguagens) ao *dereferenciar* automaticamente o conteúdo das variáveis, sem introduzir uma sintaxe específica para isso.

A `String` em Java não é um tipo primitivo, mas sim um tipo referenciado, por isso o comparador `==` realiza uma comparação verificando se duas variáveis referenciam o mesmo "endereço" de memória. Se tiverem o mesmo conteúdo, mas em endereços de memória distintos, o comparador `==` retornará falso. Já o método `equals`(e o muito útil `equalsIgnoreCase`) compara o conteúdo, em si, de cada string, verificando todos os caracteres para retornar verdadeiro caso sejam iguais, ou falso, caso contrário.

Answer (score 0):

O Erro está acontecendo pois você está inicializando o objeto "local" só se a query trouxer dados, se ela não trouxer você nunca inicializa ela e portanto fica sempre como "null", antes da comparação adicione uma validação para isso

```
if (local != null) {
// faça a comparação
} else {
// retorne informando que o local não existe, no seu caso "return 0"
}
```

Agora sobre verificar se é igual, não faça comparação de Strings com "==", apesar dos nomes serem visualmente iguais, internamente o Java pode entender que são coisas diferentes, por via de regra, utilize sempre as funções equals() ou equalsIgnoreCase()

link para um ótimo post sobre comparação de Strings.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3954/57900

Ex de comparações.

```
String nome = "Thiago";

if (nome.equals("Thiago")) {
// retorno verdadeiro
} 

if (nome.equals("thiago")) {
// retorno falso
}

if (nome.equalsIgnoreCase("Thiago")) {
// retorno verdadeiro
} 

if (nome.equalsIgnoreCase("thiago")) {
// retorno verdadeiro
}
```

Edit: Então, juntando as duas respostas e seguindo a linha do seu programa, ele deveria ficar parecido com o código abaixo

```
Local local = null;

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

    local = new Local();

    do {

        local.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        local.setLocal(cursor.getString(1));
        local.setEndereco(cursor.getString(2));
        local.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
        local.setTelefone(cursor.getString(4));
        local.setAvaliacao(cursor.getFloat(5));

    } while ( cursor . moveToNext ());

}

if (local != null) {
    comparacao = local.getLocal();

    if (nomeLocal.equalsIgnoreCase(comparacao)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: olá ... agradeço a ajuda porem, o erro persiste ... fiz como você falou loudenvier ... e como voce disse thiago .. porem o erro é o mesmo ... me parece que a variavel compara não esta pegando o valor de local.getlocal .... usei o equalsingnorecase e ele para quando chega nesta parte ... e o equals normal tbm ... ficou assim o codigo

Comment: if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            local = new Local();

            do {

                local.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                local.setLocal(cursor.getString(1));
                local.setEndereco(cursor.getString(2));
                local.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
                local.setTelefone(cursor.getString(4));
                local.setAvaliacao(cursor.getFloat(5));

            } while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }
    comparacao = local.getLocal();
    if (nomeLocal.equalsIgnoreCase(comparacao)) {

 return 1;

 }else {
return 0;
}

Comment: puts ... ficou sem identação o codigo ... pelo desculpas...

Comment: o codigo não cabeu aqui ... mas de qualquer forma .. so foi colocado o ignore case e o erro persiste ... se puderem ajudara agradeço

Comment: @Loudenvier existe mas alguma mandeira de eu pegar a informacao e colocar dentro da variavel para comparar ? ... parece que não esta dando certo aquele jeito

Comment: eu entendi o que você disse ... só não sei como colocar  aqui ... pode dar um exemplo de como seria o certo ?

Comment: @Filipe veja a minha resposta, editei ela e acrescentei uma resposta mais completa de como deveria ficar o seu código, adapta ele no seu programa e veja resolve.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda ... como eu disse estou começando a desenvolver ... e meu erro foi de logica msm ... falo so aquele else no final ali pra dar certo ... muito obrigado pela sua ajuda ... vlw msm

Comment: @Loudenvier obrigado a você tambem ... me ajudou muito! vlw msm