# Android - Comparação entre string e varchar

Tags: java, android, mysql

Estou com problemas numa comparação entre Strings.
Uma retiro de um **EditText** e a outra de uma tabela SQL.
A app consiste num jogo do género "*Who wants to be a millionare?*"

Quando chega ao ciclo if de comparação entre as duas strings:

```
if (pass_jogador == verifica_pass) {...
```

passa diretamente para o *else* correspondente.

Quando utilizo a aplicação e introduzo os dados, uso uma *Toast* para verificar se as duas strings são iguais:

```
 apresenta_toast(verifica_pass);
                apresenta_toast(pass_jogador);
```

e o resultado é o mesmo, indicam-me que as strings são iguais.

Aqui está o meu código na totalidade:

```
 int id = v.getId();

    if (id == btn_login.getId()) {
        //verificar se jogador existe
        //verificar a password
        //faz login
        String verifica_email = this.email.getText().toString();
        String verifica_pass = this.password.getText().toString();
        if (verifica_email != null && verifica_pass != null) {
            MyDBHelper dbHelper = new MyDBHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Jogador WHERE email_jogador = '" + verifica_email + "'", null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String pass_jogador = cursor.getString(2);
                //verifica a igualdade das passwords
                apresenta_toast(verifica_pass);
                apresenta_toast(pass_jogador);
                if (pass_jogador == verifica_pass) {
                    Jogador player = criaJogador(cursor, db);

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
```

Aqui a tabela e os dados do utilizador que introduzi por defeito:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Jogador (email_jogador VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, genero VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, status VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, pontuacao INTEGER, perguntasC INTEGER)");



 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Jogador(email_jogador, nome, password, genero, status, pontuacao, perguntasC) VALUES ('zld@gmail.com', 'Zé', 'qwerty', 'masculino','dealer', 0, 0)");
```

Comment: Pode usar o equals, para comparar as String 

if(pass_jogador.equals(verifica_pass))

Comment: @rodrigo.oliveira obrigado, é mesmo esta a resposta que estava a procura! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tipo String são objetos e para comparar deve usar o equals para fazer a comparação entres elas.

```
if (pass_jogador.equals(verifica_pass) ){..}
```

[Sugiro que de uma lida nessa resposta:](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java)