# Problema a verificar a lista

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema que não percebo porque, é o seguinte:
Quando eu vou add um item a lista, ele tem de verificar se esse item ja esta na lista mas ele nao esta fazendo isso.

```
if(textNameD.getText().length() > 0 && textNota.getText().length() > 0) {
        String nameD = textNameD.getText().toString();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
            listItem item = list.get(i);
            Log.d("D","1 ."+nameD+". | ."+item.name+".");
            if (item.name == nameD) {
                Log.d("D","2");
                showNotificacion(view,"A disciplina "+item.name+" já existe!");
                return;
            }
            Log.d("D","3");
        }
        Log.d("D","4");
        add(textNameD.getText().toString(),stringToInt(textNota.getText().toString()));
        textNameD.setText("");
        textNota.setText("");
    }else {
        showNotificacion(view,"Preenche todos os espacos!");
    }
```

E esta a receber o seguinte no log:

> D/D: 1 .gg. | .gg.
>   D/D: 3
>   D/D: 4

A verificação esta a receber que item.name=gg e o nameD=gg mas ele não esta a passar para if, ele esta a saltar para o o log 3.

Se alguem souber como resolver ou fazer de outra manheira agradecia:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`==` compara referências. Duas `Strings` podem ter referências diferentes, mesmo que com valores iguais. Tente mudar:

```
if (item.name == nameD)
```

Para:

```
if (Objects.equals(item.name, nameD))
```

Observação. No exemplo acima usei `Object#equals` porque um dos objetos comparados pode estar nulo. Se você tem certeza que um dos objetos não é nulo, podes usar `String#equals` direto:

```
if (item.name.equals(nameD))
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
  if (item.name.equals(nameD)) {
                Log.d("D","2");
                showNotificacion(view,"A disciplina "+item.name+" já existe!");
                return;
            }
```

[Segue uma leitura a respeito deste erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java)