# Ler string e chamar em voz java

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber qual *API* posso utilizar em JAVA, para o seguinte cenário, em que eu tenho uma String com uma senha, por exemplo, e o programa ler a String e chava por voz.

Comment: Experimenta o [FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php)

Comment: Estou dando uma olhada. Mais não achei um exemplo de implementação.

Comment: Tem aqui os demos do [FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php#run_demo)

Comment: Queria em português.

Comment: O FreeTTS é uma api bem conhecida e śolida pra leitura de texto e transformação em voz... dá uma olhada..
http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o serviço do [IBM Bluemix - Watson/Text to Speech](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/text-to-speech.html). O primeiro milhão de caractere mensal é gratuito e após isso tem um custo de $0,02 a cada mil caracteres. Lá tem uma voz referente ao português (Isabela).

A dependência do [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud/text-to-speech) para a [última versão (3.5.3)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud/text-to-speech/3.5.3) pode ser adicionada com a seguinte declaração no `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>text-to-speech</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

As vozes disponíveis podem ser encontradas na documentação [Specifying a voice](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/http.shtml#voices) e os formatos disponíveis em [Specifying an audio format](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/http.shtml#format).

Uma classe de exemplo do funcionamento:

```
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.http.ServiceCall;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.text_to_speech.v1.TextToSpeech;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.text_to_speech.v1.model.AudioFormat;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.text_to_speech.v1.model.Voice;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.text_to_speech.v1.util.WaveUtils;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Teste {

  public void sintetizar(String texto) {
    TextToSpeech servico = new TextToSpeech("USUARIO DA CREDENCIAL", "SENHA DA CREDENCIAL");
    Map<String, String> opcoes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ServiceCall<InputStream> chamada;
    InputStream retorno;
    AudioInputStream tocavel;
    Clip execucao;
    FloatControl volume;

    // Realiza a chamada do serviço
    opcoes.put("accept", "audio/wav;rate=8000");
    servico.setDefaultHeaders(opcoes);
    chamada = servico.synthesize(texto,
            new Voice("pt-BR_IsabelaVoice", null, null),
            new AudioFormat("audio/wav"));
    retorno = chamada.execute(); // Aguarda o retorno

    try {
      tocavel = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(WaveUtils.reWriteWaveHeader(retorno));
      execucao = AudioSystem.getClip();
      execucao.open(tocavel);
      execucao.start(); // Inicia a execução do som
      // Aumenta o volume
      volume = (FloatControl) execucao.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
      volume.setValue(volume.getMaximum());
      execucao.drain(); // Aguarda a execução
      execucao.close(); // Fecha o player
      retorno.close();
    } catch (IOException | LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Teste.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Teste teste = new Teste();

    teste.sintetizar("Meu texto");
  }
}
```

O usuário e senha utilizados são os da credencial que é criada quando o `Text to Speech` é habilitado no painel do `Bluemix`.

Exemplo das credenciais:

[image: Exemplo das credenciais]

Este é um repositório no Github que possui a implementação [Sorackb/WatsonTextToSpeechSample](https://github.com/Sorackb/WatsonTextToSpeechSample).

Comment: A dependência do Maven para a última versão (3.5.3) pode ser adicionada com a seguinte declaração no pom.xml -- Por favor, pode me dizer como fazer isso?

Comment: @JesséSantos não entendi sua dúvida

Comment: Nessa informação "A dependência Mave pode ser adicionada com a seguinte declaração", Eu tenho que inserir essa declaração? Caso sim, como faço isso? Já criei minha conta, utilizei essa classe teste, alterei usuario e senha, e inserir a biblioteca .jar do maven, porém essas linhas apareceram com erro: import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.http.ServiceCall;   ServiceCall<InputStream> chamada; servico.setDefaultHeaders(opcoes); chamada = servico.synthesize(texto,
            new Voice("pt-BR_IsabelaVoice", null, null),
            new AudioFormat("audio/wav"));

Comment: @JesséSantos O maven possui um arquivo de configuração. O `pom.xml`. Porém se você não está familiarizado com o maven, eu te aconselho a usar a biblioteca do Watson diretamente. Aqui está o [link](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/java-sdk/3.5.3/java-sdk-3.5.3.jar) para download.

Comment: Basta adicionar essa biblioteca?

Comment: @JesséSantos sim

Answer (score -3):

Você pode simplesmente criar métodos para isso exemplo e usar o AudioClip:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     String senha = "SENHA123";

     if(senha == "SENHA"){
         executar();
     }
}

public void executar(){
    AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(urlDoSom);
    clip.start();//toca só uma vez
    clip.loop();//toca o som repetidamente 
    clip.stop();//para de tocar
}
```

Fonte: [GUJ](http://www.guj.com.br/t/como-executar-aquivos-de-som-wav-mp3-etc-numa-aplicacao-java/107422/3)

Comment: Acho que isso não responde a pergunta. Pelo que eu entendi ele quer que o conteúdo da string seja reproduzido por voz, não tocar um som ao comparar a referência de dois objetos. A propósito, [como comparar strings em Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/4808).