# passagem de parametros entre activitys

Tags: java, android

poderiam me ajudar com este codigo do android studio ...eu nao cosnigo recuperar o string para rodar o if:

```
public void Green(View view) {
        String cor3 = "verde";

        Bundle parametros = new Bundle();
        parametros.putString("verde",cor3);
        Intent it =  new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        parametros.putString("verde",cor3);
        it.putExtras(parametros);
        startActivity(it);
```

2ª tela

```
Intent intent = getIntent();        
String verde = intent.getStringExtra("verde");

 if ( cor=="verde"){
            btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            btn2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            btn3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            btn4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
```

eu rodo o emulado e nao funfa

Comment: O problema é que você está a receber o valor na variável `verde` e no `if` está a usar a variável `cor`. Por outro lado deve usar, para a comparação, o método `equals()` e não `==`.

Answer (score 1):

A comparação de string no Java deve ser feito pelo método **equals**.

```
if (cor.equals("verde")) { ...
```

Um link aqui do stackoverflow explicando:
[Como comparar Strings em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java)

Comment: Não necessáriamente precisar ser comparado desta forma @Paulo C, vai do costume do desenvolvedor...

Comment: ok..agora foi ..muito obrigado!

Comment: @Matheus, a partir de qual versão do java a comparação de string pode ser direta com o ==?

Comment: Qual a relevancia desta pergutna ??

Comment: Somente curiosidade. Por a String ser um objeto, pensei que era somente com o equals que poderia ser feito a comparação.

Comment: Então Paulo hehe tipo põe na sua cabeça que tudo é extende a classe Object, tipo se você fizer isso String cor = "Verde"; Object obj = cor; vai funcionar, mas será um Object, com tudo para você pegar o valor da String você teria que usar um cast para transforma-la de object para string. Quanto a sua pergunta, na linguagem java sempre deu para fazer comparação de String desta forma.

Comment: @Matheus Sempre deu e dá. O problema é que não dá sempre. Assim, se quer saber se o **valor** de dois String são iguais use `equals()`. O uso de `==` deve ser usado para verificar se é o mesmo objecto(referência).

Comment: @ramaral você que é um usuário mais experiente em java hehe é o cara exato para responder esta pergunta, contudo Paulo C, você não consiguira comparar strings de instancias diferentes, tipo assim String str = "teste"; String str2 = new String("teste"); (str == str2) // false entende ?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta dessa forma:

1° Tela.

```
public void Green(View view) {
Intent it =  new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
it.putExtra("verde",cor3);
startActivity(it);
}
```

E para recuperar:

2° Tela.

```
Intent it = getIntent();
String color;
Bundle bd = it.getExtras();       
if(bd != null)
{
   color = (String) bd.get("verde");           
}

if ( color.equals("verde")) // EDITED
{
   btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
   btn2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
   btn3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
   btn4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Comment: Ok, funcionou ...valew ...o problema estava realmente na comparação do java

Comment: @RafaelUemura caso tenha sido concluida a resposta, marque como resposta correta... Obrigado.