# Comparação request.getParameter com String JSP

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Estou querendo  pegar o que o usuário vai digitar com `request.getParameter` e comparar com uma String e se o valor que o usuário digitar for igual a string, o usuário ser redirecionado para a pagina mas isso não está acontecendo.

```
 String login = request.getParameter("login");
      String senha = request.getParameter("senha");

     if(login=="Felipe_Massa_10" && senha=="felipemassa1010"){
      RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/CadastroProdutos.jsp");
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja a pergunta [como comparar strings em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/4808)

Da forma que está fazendo, a comparação está sendo feita pela referência e não pelo conteúdo da string. Utilize `equals()` para realizar a verificação:

```
String login = request.getParameter("login"),
       senha = request.getParameter("senha");

if(login.equals("Felipe_Massa_10") && senha.equals("felipemassa1010"))
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/CadastroProdutos.jsp")
          .forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nunca use == para comparar string em Java. O == é usado para comparar referëncias em memória, equanto o .equals() é usado para comparar os valores em si, mas lembre-se que possíveis nullPointerExceptions podem ocorrer, logo coloque a constante do lado esquerdo, usando uma prática chamada "never-null-pointer", e ficaria assim: "Felipe_Massa_10".equals(login) ao invés de login.equals("Felipe_Massa_10"). Se login for null, então false é retornado.