# Problema com while no java (exercicio simples)

Tags: java, while

Contexto: estou fazendo um algoritmo que guarde strings aleatorias digitadas pelo usuario num vetor de strings até que o usuario digite "parar".

problema: ao digitar parar, o eclipse continua o loop no while, e no if (palavraDigitada != "parar"), mesmo que a palavraDigitada == parar ele continua entrando nesse if.

codigo:

```
while (palavraDigitada != "parar") {

        System.out.print("Escreva quaisquer string ou digite parar para buscar: ");         
        palavraDigitada = tec.next();
        if (palavraDigitada != "parar") {
            if (palavrasEmLista == "") {
                palavrasEmLista = palavraDigitada;
            }

            else {
                palavrasEmLista = palavrasEmLista + ";" + palavraDigitada;
            }               
            contador++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não use `==` ou `!=` para comparar `String`s. Use o método `equals`. Veja a [**pergunta linkada**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/132) para entender o porquê.