# Por que o printf não concatena?

Tags: java

Sou um inovador em Java e estou com problemas porque o `printf` não concatena duas quantias com uma variável, vez que o `println` deixa eu trabalhar com decimais mas não funciona com eles. Veja:

```
if (this.consulta == "health plan") {
    system.out.printf ("priority =% .2f% n", this.value Query, "\ ndespense 20.00");
}
else {
    system.out.printf ("xonvenio, this.valorConsulta);
}
```

Comment: Traduza sua pergunta. Sanando seu problema, para concatenar você de utilizar o sinal de *Mais* ( `+` ) e não *Virgula* ( `,` ) ... `"priority =% .2f% n" + this.value Query + "\ ndespense 20.00"`

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow in Portuguese. If you want to ask questions in english go to  https://stackoverflow.com/, or translate your question

Comment: Traduzi "*two mounts*" como "*duas quantias*", mas não sei se essa seria a melhor tradução no seu caso.

Comment: Achei muito estranho o termo "inovador em Java", e quando vi no texto original achei mais estranho ainda o.O

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Se ele é um inovador em Java, então fico imaginando o que eu seria.

Answer (score 3):

O seu código não compila por vários motivos:

1. Você usa vírgulas para concatenar. Deveria usar `+`.
2. Você não fecha a string que começa com `"xonvenio`. Aliás, acho que você está a falar de "*convênio*", e não de "*xonvenio*".
3. Você está usando `system` com letra minúscula ao invés de `System` com letra maiúscula.
4. [Comparar strings com `==` não vai fazer o que você quer.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/132)
5. Aquele `\ n` não deveria ter um espaço no meio.
6. A sua string de formatação `"priority =% .2f% n"` está mal-formada.

E realmente, `printf` não concatena nada, o motivo é que `printf` não é um método de concatenação, e sim um método para colocar dados em um modelo de texto.

Quanto essa sua afirmação de que `println` não trabalhar com decimais, ela está errada. O seu problema é na verdade que eles não vem formatados como você quer, o que é algo completamente diferente. A solução seria formatá-los adequadamente antes.

Infelizmente, vê-se que você não domina conceitos básicos sobre Java. Assim sendo, não ouse denominar-se um inovador em Java enquanto não for capaz de dominar os conceitos básicos da linguagem.