# Eu não consigo pegar o valor da variável de diferentes classes

Tags: java

meus colegas boa noite eu me socorre aqui , estou fazeno um trabalho para faculdade , sou iniciante em Java , eu não consigo passa tenho 2 class 1 -paciente 2 medico, a classe medico ja esta com extends do paciente , mais eu não consigo passar o nome do paciente para a classe medico

```
public void receita () {
if (this.consultaMedica == "dor de cabeça") {
System.out.println ("\nPrescrição: O paciente " + getNomeDoPaciente () + " está com foi marcado com o remédio dipirona");
```

e tambem não consigo passa data data que esta na classe secretara oara aclasse paciente

```
public void data(int dia, int mes,int ano) {
data = ( dia +"/" + mes + "/" + ano);

        }
public class Paciente {
private String nomeDoPaciente;
private int idadeDoPaciente;
private String cpfDoPaciente;

public class Secretaria {
private String nomeCompleto;
private double valorDaConsulta = 360.77; //so coloquei esse centavos ai pra formatar a casa decimail , mas so o printf que faz porém não concatena 2 frases, depois vc me explica a fiferença de prinF e printLN 
String Consulta;
String data;

public void data(int dia, int mes,int ano) {
    data = ( dia  +"/" + mes + "/" + ano);
}   
]public void mostrarPaciente(){

    System.out.printf("\nCadastro do Paciente"+"\n===INFORMAÇÕES DO PACIENTE==="+
"\nNome do paciente: " + getNomeDoPaciente() +"\n"+
                        "Idade do paciente: "+ getIdadeDoPaciente() + "\n"+
                        "CPF: " + getCpfDoPaciente()+ "\nData agendada: "+getDataInicio())
```

Comment: Este é o Stack em português jovem, traduz sua pergunta.

Comment: Por favor, poste a dúvida em português e formate o código a ponto de ele ficar legível

Comment: desculpas..........

Comment: Olha, tentei salvar a sua pergunta traduzindo e formatando ela, mas claramente o código resultante está tão incompleto e desorganizado que não é algo lá muito usável. Sugiro postar um código que seja ao menos compilável (edite a pergunta para fazer isso).

Comment: E vale a dica que dei na resposta da sua outra pergunta acerca de usar `==` com strings: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/132

Comment: "*a classe medico ja esta com extends do paciente*" - não faça isso! O `extends` quer dizer "*é um*". É incorreto afirmar que um médico **é um** paciente, e portanto, se você programar desse jeito, o seu programa não vai sair o que você espera.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada (não é duplicata): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251819/132

Answer (score 3):

Não vou entrar no mérito dos inúmeros erros de compilação do seu código postado incompleto, nem nos problemas estruturais que "*medico extends paciente*" causa [<sup>**[1]**</sup>](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#The_CoITO), nem na estranheza que é o fato de uma `Secretaria` ter uma consulta (pensei que quem tinha consulta era o paciente) [<sup>**[2]**</sup>](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Programa.C3.A7.C3.A3o_Desorientada_a_Objetos), nem no problema de datas serem representadas como strings [<sup>**[3]**</sup>](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Programa.C3.A7.C3.A3o_Orientada_a_Strings) e nem no problema de comparar strings com `==` [<sup>**[4]**</sup>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/132).

O fato é que para resolver o seu problema, você pode usar um setter. Por exemplo, na classe `Paciente`, você coloca isso:

```
private String dataConsulta;

public void setDataConsulta(String dataConsulta) {
    this.dataConsulta = dataConsulta;
}
```

Então, na classe `Secretaria`, você faz isso:

```
p1.setDataConsulta(data);
```

Você pode estar perguntando de onde veio essa variável `p1`. Ela é uma instância de um paciente. Você pode criar uma instância assim:

```
Paciente p1 = new Paciente();
p1.setNome("João");
p1.setCpf("123.456.789-10");
```

Observe aí o uso dos métodos `setNome` e `setCpf`, eles são usados para definir os dados do paciente.

Você pode criar várias instâncias diferentes de diferentes classes e fazê-las interagir por meio de métodos:

```
Especialidade ortopedia = new Especialidade();
ortopedia.setNome("ortopedia");

Especialidade cardiologia = new Especialidade();
cardiologia.setNome("cardiologia");

Especialidade pediatria = new Especialidade();
pediatria.setNome("pediatria");

Secretaria s1 = new Secretaria();
s1.setNome("Carlos");

Secretaria s2 = new Secretaria();
s2.setNome("Maria");

Medico m1 = new Medico();
m1.setNome("Paulo");
m1.setEspecialidade(ortopedia);

Medico m2 = new Medico();
m2.setNome("Valéria");
m2.setEspecialidade(pediatria);

Paciente p1 = new Paciente();
p1.setNome("João");
p1.setCpf("123.456.789-10");

Paciente p2 = new Paciente();
p2.setNome("Fernanda");
p2.setCpf("987.654.321-00");

s1.atender(p1);
s2.atender(p2);
```

Talvez você ache algumas coisas do código acima um pouco repetitivas. É que na verdade há formas de se simplificar isso, deixando o código mais simples e menos repetitivo. Mas como você ainda está em um estado muito inicial no aprendizado de Java, deixemos isso para depois.

Comment: +1 pelo primeiro parágrafo :)