# javax.servlet.ServletException

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlet

Estou fazendo um cadastramento básico de usuários com `Servlet`.

Quando eu clico no botão de cadastrar recebo a seguinte página de erro (tudo foi revisado e está em perfeito funcionamento, acredito que seja algo relacionado com o Hibernate, mas nada do que eu tendo resolve):

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet execution threw an exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:88)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:61)
    org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:101)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:50)
    org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    servlet.CadastroServlet.doPost(CadastroServlet.java:87)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.33
```

**Este é o meu persistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence version="2.1" 
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns: 
  xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="prova3bPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
  <class>model.entities.Users</class>
   <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  <properties>
   <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" 
   value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
   value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prova3b"/>
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
   value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="t759m1546"/>
   <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" 
   value="create"/>
 </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Este é o meu servlet:**

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        String nome = request.getParameter("username");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String senha = request.getParameter("password");
        String confirm_senha = request.getParameter("confirm_senha");

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("prova3bPU");
        UsersJpaController objJpa = new UsersJpaController(emf);

        Users user = new Users();
        user.setUsername(nome);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(senha);

        if(senha == confirm_senha){
            objJpa.create(user); 
            request.setAttribute("resp", "efetuado");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("cadastro_response.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("resp", "negado");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("cadatro_response.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        processRequest(request, response); 
}
```

Comment: Favor **[edit]** a pergunta adicionando o persistence.xml. O problema de colocar somente links é que eles podem estar inacessíveis (que é o que aconteceu agora, tentei acessar o codeshare mas está dando erro). Colocando-o na pergunta, todos podem ter a informação completa sem depender de outros sites. Entenda melhor em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5489/112052

Comment: Boa tarde amigo, agradeço pelo comentario. Acabei de fazer a edição, espero que melhore o entendimento da pergunta e consiga me ajudar...

Comment: O que tem na linha 87 do `CadastroServlet.java`? Edite sua pergunta e poste o código para a gente ver, por favor. Ah, e a sua comparação de strings `if (senha == confirm_senha)` está errada, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java) (e tenha cuidado com strings nulas).

Comment: Certo, substitui a comparação para "if(senha.equals(confirm_senha))" e o conteudo da linha 87 é a declaração do EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("prova3bPU");