# Sempre que executo sempre imprime Login inválido

Tags: java

/*  Faça um algoritmo que verifique se o login e senha informados pelo
usuário está correto. O algoritmo deve solicitar do usuário: login e
senha, e verificar em um conjunto de 3 informações armazenadas
em variáveis. Caso o usuário informe os dados corretos, o
algoritmo deve imprimir uma mensagem de "Login e senha
corretos", caso o contrário "Login ou senha inválido". O algoritmo
será concluído se o usuário acertar as informações ou errar 3
vezes. */

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class exercicio5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String login = "admin" ; String senha="1234"; int count = 1; String digite;

    while (count<=3) {
        System.out.print ("Digite o login:");
        digite = sc.next();
        if (login==digite) {
            System.out.print ("Digite a senha:\n");
            digite = sc.next();
            if (digite==senha){
                count=3;
            }
        } else  {
            System.out.print("Login invalido.\n\n");
        }
        count = count+1;
    }

    System.out.print("Concluido");


    }
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como comparar Strings em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java)

Answer (score 3):

Tenta assim :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String login = "admin" ; String senha="1234"; int count = 1; String digite;

        while (count<=3) {
            System.out.print ("Digite o login:");
            digite = sc.next();
            if (login.equals(digite)) {
                System.out.print ("Digite a senha:\n");
                digite = sc.next();
                if (digite.equals(digite)){
                    count=3;
                }
            } else  {
                System.out.print("Login invalido.\n\n");
            }
            count = count+1;
        }

        System.out.print("Concluido");


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o método equals para comparar string, da seguinte maneira

```
if (login.equals(digite)) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o método da classe String `equals()`

Observe como eu reescrevi seu programa:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class exercicio5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String login = "admin" ; String senha="1234"; int count = 1; String digite;

    while (count<=3) {
        System.out.print ("Digite o login:");
        digite = sc.next();
        if (login.equals(digite)) {
            System.out.print ("Digite a senha:\n");
            digite = sc.next();
            if (digite.equals(senha)){
                count=3;
            }
        } else  {
            System.out.print("Login invalido.\n\n");
        }
        count = count+1;
    }

    System.out.print("Concluido");


    }
}
```

Quando você compara dois objetos usando `==`, você está comparando se os dois objetos são iguais, ou seja, se apontam para o mesmo endereço de memória. Como objetos são instâncias **diferentes** de uma mesma classe, a melhor forma de compará-los é usando métodos criados para este fim, como o `equals()`.