# Problema ao comparar Strings no Java durante o loop do while

Tags: java

Estou com essa atividade da faculdade e estou tendo problema ao encerrar o loop do meu while, pois mesmo após Informar que o nome da cidade é Zimbabue de Minas ele considera como diferente e continuar executando, segue o código:

```
package problemas.iniciante;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problema1019 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nomeDaCidade = "", cidadeMenorPop = "";
        int populacao, numEleitores, qntMulheres, qntHomens, totalDeCidades = 0, popTotal = 0,
                totalEleitores = 0, maisMulheres = 0, menorPop = 0;
        double mediaHomens = 0;
        Scanner leia1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner leia2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (nomeDaCidade != "Zimbabue de Minas") {
            System.out.print("Informe o nome da cidade: ");
            nomeDaCidade = leia1.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Informe o número de habitantes desta cidade: ");
            populacao = leia2.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Informe o número de eleitores desta cidade: ");
            numEleitores = leia2.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Informe a quantidade de homens da cidade: ");
            qntHomens = leia2.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Informe a quantidade de mulheres da cidade: ");
            qntMulheres = leia2.nextInt();
            if (qntHomens + qntMulheres != populacao) {
                System.out.println("A soma dos homens mais mulheres é diferente da população da cidade");
            }
            totalDeCidades++;
            popTotal += populacao;
            totalEleitores += numEleitores;
            if (qntMulheres > qntHomens) {
                maisMulheres++;
            }
            mediaHomens += qntHomens;
            if (totalDeCidades == 1 || populacao < menorPop) {
                menorPop = populacao;
                cidadeMenorPop = nomeDaCidade;
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("Total de cidades: %d\n", totalDeCidades);
        System.out.printf("População total: %d\n", popTotal);
        System.out.printf("Percentual de eleitores: %.2f%\n", totalEleitores / popTotal * 100);
        System.out.printf("Quanidade de cidades com mais mulheres do que homens: %d\n", maisMulheres);
        mediaHomens /= totalDeCidades;
        System.out.printf("Média dos homens: %.2f\n", mediaHomens);
        System.out.print("Cidade com menor população " + cidadeMenorPop);

        leia1.close();
        leia2.close();
    }
}
```

Também aceito dicas de boas práticas neste código

Comment: Você precisa utilizar o método equals para comparar strings em Java [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no comparador que você está utilizando. Comparação de igualdade, em java, só deve utilizar os comparadores `==` ou `!=` para tipos primitivos.

Como String é uma classe e não um tipo primitivo, o correto seria utilizar o método `equals()`

Logo, no seu código ficaria:

```
while (nomeDaCidade == null || !nomeDaCidade.equals("Zimbabue de Minas"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Opa!

Altere o trecho do código:

```
 while (nomeDaCidade != "Zimbabue de Minas") {
```

para

```
 while (!"Zimbabue de Minas".equals(nomeDaCidade)) {
```

Sempre procure usar o "equals" para comparação de strings. Perceba que inverti a sua comparação, pois desta forma evita um possível nullpointer caso a string nomeDaCidade esteja nula.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Bem lembrado! :) hehe Ajustado..