# Filtro De lista em Java

Tags: java

Eu estou filtrar um `ArrayList<ArrayList<>>` que possuo para verificar se certos dados ja foram inseridos dentro dele, deta forma:

```
int index = produtos.indexOf(produtos.stream().filter((x) -> x.get(0).Nome == prod.Nome).findFirst());
```

a lista compoe listas que são listas de produtos, cada lista de produto deveria conter o mesmo registro de produto, Por isso estou tentando achar o indes do produto na `ArrayList<ArrayList<produto>>`. Porém o index vem **-1**, como se nao ouvesse o encontrado

Comment: Você tem uma lista, essa lista tem listas de produtos, e você quer achar a lista que possui o produto desejado?

Comment: Parece um problema XY, você não deseja ter duplicatas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código possui um problema principal que é a comparação de Strings, você pode ler mais sobre isso [nessa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java).

De qualquer forma, existem formas melhores de fazer o que você precisa:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Produto>> listaDeListas = Arrays.asList(
                                                Arrays.asList(new Produto("Produto 1"), new Produto("Produto 2")),
                                                Arrays.asList(new Produto("Produto 3")),
                                                Arrays.asList(new Produto("Produto 4"), new Produto("Produto 5"), new Produto("Produto 6")),
                                                Arrays.asList(new Produto("Produto 7"))
                                            );
        // Condição desejada
        Predicate<Produto> filtroProduto = p -> p.getNome().equalsIgnoreCase("Produto 1");

        // Recupera a lista contendo o produto
        List<Produto> listaComOcorrencia = listaDeListas.stream()
                                            .flatMap(List::stream)
                                            .filter(filtroProduto)
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(listaComOcorrencia);

        // Recupera a contagem de produtos com o critério
        long count = listaDeListas.stream()
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .filter(filtroProduto)
                        .count();
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    @Data
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static class Produto {
        private final String nome;
    }
}
```

A saída do programa é:

```
[Main.Produto(nome=Produto 1)]
1
```

Onde na primeira stream, eu recuperei a(s) lista(s) contendo o produto, e as agrupei.

Provavelmente o segundo filtro é o mais interessante, visto que apenas recupera uma contagem de produtos atendendo aquela condição. Você então pode comparar e ver se o produto já foi colocado utilizando `count != 0`.

De qualquer forma, se você NÃO deseja duplicatas, e não quer trabalho de ficar comparando se o objeto já existe, você deve utilizar a estrutura [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), que não permite duplicatas

Comment: Ola, obrigado pela resposta!
Fora a comparação direta de strings que eu havia feito no meu exemplo pelo que eu entendi a operação foi a mesma, não? a unica diferença foi o armazenamento da condição em uma variavel. Porém seu metodo funcionou, saberia me dizer o por que?

Comment: Acho que a maior diferença está no código ficar mais legível, com um count você tem a informação de contagem total, o que torna mais facil durante a leitura do código identificar que você gostaria de verificar se algum dos itens existe na lista. Com o índice funciona? Sim! Mas a informação durante a leitura não fica tão clara a primeira vista, comparando se o índice é != -1 por exemplo