# Não estou conseguindo criar array com chaves em Java

Tags: java, array, sintaxe

Estou estudando a linguagem Java e para praticar estou criando um programa simples de login. Possuo uma classe chamada `Database` que deveria guardar um array com as informações (nome e senha) dos usuários.

O problema é que ao tentar compilar o código, o compilador aponta um erro onde está sendo inicializado o array. Veja abaixo o código e o erro:

```
public class Database{

    private static String[][] data = new String[5][2];

    {
        Database.data[0] = {"Jean", "pato_34"};
        Database.data[1] = {"Maria", "lolzin"};
        Database.data[2] = {"Lucas", "bot3000"};
        Database.data[3] = {"Pedro", "showd3b0la"};
    }

    public static String[] find(String username){

        for (String[] user : Database.data){

            if (username == user[0]){
                return user;
            }
        }

        return {"", ""};
    }
}
```

---

```
.\server\Database.java:8: error: illegal start of expression
        Database.data[0] = {"Jean", "pato_34"};
                           ^
.\server\Database.java:8: error: not a statement
        Database.data[0] = {"Jean", "pato_34"};
                            ^
.\server\Database.java:8: error: ';' expected
        Database.data[0] = {"Jean", "pato_34"};
                                  ^
.\server\Database.java:9: error: ']' expected
        Database.data[1] = {"Maria", "lolzin"};
                      ^
.\server\Database.java:9: error: ';' expected
        Database.data[1] = {"Maria", "lolzin"};
                       ^
.\server\Database.java:9: error: illegal start of type
        Database.data[1] = {"Maria", "lolzin"};
                         ^
.\server\Database.java:9: error: <identifier> expected
        Database.data[1] = {"Maria", "lolzin"};
                          ^
.\server\Database.java:9: error: ';' expected
        Database.data[1] = {"Maria", "lolzin"};
                            ^
.\server\Database.java:9: error: illegal start of type
        Database.data[1] = {"Maria", "lolzin"};
                                   ^
.\server\Database.java:9: error: <identifier> expected
        Database.data[1] = {"Maria", "lolzin"};
                                    ^
.\server\Database.java:9: error: ';' expected
        Database.data[1] = {"Maria", "lolzin"};
                                             ^
.\server\Database.java:10: error: ']' expected
        Database.data[2] = {"Lucas", "bot3000"};
                      ^
.\server\Database.java:10: error: ';' expected
        Database.data[2] = {"Lucas", "bot3000"};
                       ^
.\server\Database.java:10: error: illegal start of type
        Database.data[2] = {"Lucas", "bot3000"};
                         ^
.\server\Database.java:10: error: <identifier> expected
        Database.data[2] = {"Lucas", "bot3000"};
                          ^
.\server\Database.java:10: error: ';' expected
        Database.data[2] = {"Lucas", "bot3000"};
                            ^
.\server\Database.java:10: error: illegal start of type
        Database.data[2] = {"Lucas", "bot3000"};
                                   ^
.\server\Database.java:10: error: <identifier> expected
        Database.data[2] = {"Lucas", "bot3000"};
                                    ^
.\server\Database.java:10: error: ';' expected
        Database.data[2] = {"Lucas", "bot3000"};
                                              ^
.\server\Database.java:11: error: ']' expected
        Database.data[3] = {"Pedro", "showd3b0la"};
                      ^
.\server\Database.java:11: error: ';' expected
        Database.data[3] = {"Pedro", "showd3b0la"};
                       ^
.\server\Database.java:11: error: illegal start of type
        Database.data[3] = {"Pedro", "showd3b0la"};
                         ^
.\server\Database.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
        Database.data[3] = {"Pedro", "showd3b0la"};
                          ^
.\server\Database.java:11: error: ';' expected
        Database.data[3] = {"Pedro", "showd3b0la"};
                            ^
.\server\Database.java:11: error: illegal start of type
        Database.data[3] = {"Pedro", "showd3b0la"};
                                   ^
.\server\Database.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
        Database.data[3] = {"Pedro", "showd3b0la"};
                                    ^
.\server\Database.java:11: error: ';' expected
        Database.data[3] = {"Pedro", "showd3b0la"};
                                                 ^
.\server\Database.java:14: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    public static String[] find(String username){
                  ^
.\server\Database.java:20: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            }
            ^
.\server\Database.java:24: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
.\server\Database.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        Database.data[1] = {"Maria", "lolzin"};
                ^
  symbol:   class data
  location: class Database
.\server\Database.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        Database.data[2] = {"Lucas", "bot3000"};
                ^
  symbol:   class data
  location: class Database
.\server\Database.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        Database.data[3] = {"Pedro", "showd3b0la"};
                ^
  symbol:   class data
  location: class Database
Main.java:6: error: Client(String,String) has private access in Client
        Client client = new Client("Jean", "pato_34");
                        ^
.\server\Session.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        String[] user = Database.find(username);
                                ^
  symbol:   method find(String)
  location: class Database
35 errors
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Sei que é algo relacionado a sintaxe mas não consigo entender onde está o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A criação de arrays em Java é meio chatinha mesmo.

Essa maneira que você tentou só funciona se for na própria declaração da variável. Ex:

```
String[] nomes = {"fulano", "ciclano"};
```

Mas se eu fizer em outra linha, dá erro:

```
String[] nomes;
nomes = {"fulano", "ciclano"}; // erro!
```

Nesse caso só funciona se usar `new`:

```
String[] nomes;
nomes = new String[] {"fulano", "ciclano"};
```

Portanto, no seu caso deve ser:

```
Database.data[0] = new String[] {"Jean", "pato_34"};
```

Ou então crie todos os valores de uma vez:

```
private static String[][] data = {
    {"Jean", "pato_34"},
    {"Maria", "lolzin"},
    // etc...
 };
```

Outro detalhe não relacionado é que em Java [deve-se comparar Strings com `equals`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/112052)  em vez de `==`:

```
if (username.equals(user[0]))
```

Comment: Obrigado hkotsubo <3