# Duvidas com JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou usando o driver JDBC para conectar meu programa ao banco de dados e quando uso o método getString ele me torna uma string que posso imprimir em tela mas ao comparar essa string que ele me retorna com uma outra  string de mesmo valor o resultado é falso, fiz um código para demostrar isso:
package teste;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TestesComDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Connection conexao;
         String url ="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306:/javateste";
         String user = "root";
         String password = "";
         try {
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
            Statement stmt = conexao.createStatement();
            String comando = "INSERT INTO tabProduto (codigoProduto,descProduto) VALUES(1,'bola') ";
            stmt.executeUpdate(comando);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tabProduto");
            while(rs.next()) {
                int c = rs.getInt("codigoProduto");
                String d = rs.getString("descProduto");

```
            System.out.println(d=="bola");
            System.out.println(c+" "+d);

        }

     }
     catch(SQLException exe){
         System.out.println("\nMais q porra deu um erro no sql: "+exe);
     }
     catch(Exception exe) {
         System.out.println("\nMais q porra deu um erro:"+exe);
     }

}
```

}
obs: a tabela usa da é obtida a partir do comando : create table tabProduto (codigoProduto integer, descProduto char(30));

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como comparar Strings em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para comparação de String, use o método **equals(suaString)**

Exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String palavra = "Teste";

    if(palavra.equals("Teste")) {
        System.out.println("Deu bom aqui");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Deu ruim aqui");
    }               
}
```

}