# Como comparar datas?

Tags: android, data, simpledateformat, calendario

Criei uma mascará NN/NN/NNNN no meu editText para capturar data de vencimento, sem um calendário, tudo feito no edt. Depois usei SimpleDateFormat para capturar a data atual do sistema. Fiz uma comparação com a mascara do edt e a varialvel(data atual) do simpledateformat. Mas creio que a comparação não está dando certo. Não aparece a condição criada. Digito a data atual, mas não aparece "teste"(condição que criei como teste).

Mascará de campo

```
 final EditText edtDataSelecionada = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDataSelecionada);

    //Criando a mascara de campo
    SimpleMaskFormatter smf = new SimpleMaskFormatter("NN/NN/NNNN");
    MaskTextWatcher mtw = new MaskTextWatcher(edtDataSelecionada, smf);
    edtDataSelecionada.addTextChangedListener(mtw);
    //fim da mascará
```

SimpleDateFormat e condição

```
item.setDataselecionada(String.valueOf(edtDataSelecionada.getText().toString().trim()));

                SimpleDateFormat formataData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date data = new Date();
                String dataFormatada = formataData.format(data);


                if (edtDataSelecionada.getText().toString() == dataFormatada){
                    item.setNotificacao("Teste");
                }
```

Outra coisa, eu gostaria de fazer comparações com o dd separado do MM.

Comment: O método `format` de um `SimpleDateFormat` retorna uma `String`. E em Java, [strings devem ser comparadas com `equals`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/112052), não com o operador `==`. Então bastaria fazer `if (edtDataSelecionada.getText().toString().equals(dataFormatada)) { etc... }`

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi bem a sua pergunta, mas basicamente para comparar uma data você teria que transformar `edtDataSelecionada` para um objeto `Date` e então usar a função `compareTo`.

Exemplo:

```
SimpleDateFormat formataData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date data = new Date();
String dataFormatada = formataData.format(data);

Date d1 = formataData.parse(edtDataSelecionada.getText().toString());
Date d2 = formataData.parse(dataFormatada);


if (d1.compareTo(d2) == 0){
    item.setNotificacao("Teste");
}
```

Ou então com `equals`:

```
if (d1.equals(d2)){
    item.setNotificacao("Teste");
}
```

Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-java)

Comment: Exatamente isso, consegui fazer a conversão de String para Date. Mas tenho um problema, coloquei o mesmo código no onResume da tela que está minha lista, para que as mensagens sejam passadas com a atualização da data atual. Date d1 = null;
        try {
            d1 = formataData.parse(item.getDataselecionada());// esse item.getDataselecionada está com erro.
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Comment: No caso ao que parece você está agora com um erro nesse método "getDataselecionada" mesmo.