# Retirar valores duplicados em uma lista e imprimí-los

Tags: java

Tenho um arquivo chamado `arq1.txt` e o outro `arq2.txt`.

Valores dentro do `arq1`:

```
2
5
1
10
21
7
8
8
3
```

Valores do `arq2`:

```
1,2,3
```

Nesse caso, meu trabalho é fazer a comparação entre os valores presentes nos 2 arquivos e criar um novo arquivo fazendo com que o texto escrito nele seja o valor de `arq1 - arq2`.

No caso, iria retirar os valores 1, 2 e 3 do `arq1`, ficando da seguinte forma (no caso o código criaria um 3° arquivo e armazenaria esse valor nele):

`arq3.txt`:

```
5
10
21
7
8
8
```

Até o momento consegui isso:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
 
public class App {
 
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final List<String> linhasA = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\q\\arq1.txt"));
    final List<String> linhasB = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\q\\arq2.txt"));
    
    linhasB.forEach(linhaB -> {
       linhasA.forEach(linhaA -> {
           final String []valoresLinhaB = linhaB.split("\\,");
           final String []valoresLinhaA = linhaA.split("\\,");
    
           final List<String> duplicados = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(valoresLinhaB));
           duplicados.retainAll(Arrays.asList(valoresLinhaA));
    
           if(duplicados.size() > 0){
               
             System.out.println(duplicados);
              }

        


         });
        });
    }
}
```

Dessa forma o valor retornado é:

```
[2]
[1]
[3]
```

Que no caso o código basicamente fez a comparação entre os 2 arquivos e verificou os dados duplicados.

Agora tô com uma fucking imensa dificuldade em fazer com que seja printado na tela o valor do arq1 retirando os valores duplicados.

Já tentei fazer uns comparativos mas não funcionaram(sou novo em java), algo como:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
if(valoresLinhaA[i] != duplicados){
   System.out.println(valoreslinhaA[i]);
 }
}
```

Porém o grande erro é que o `valoresLinhaA[i]` é uma string e não tem como fazer comparação dessa forma (ao menos a IDE me diz isso).

Alguma outra forma de comparar os valores e imprimir apenas o valor sem duplicação?

Sobre a criação do arquivo, acredito que consigo me virar após pegar o resultado sem os valores duplicados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso, o mais simples parece ser usar o [método `removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-). Primeiro você lê todos os valores de cada um dos arquivos, e depois faz a "subtração":

```
// método auxiliar para ler todos os valores do arquivo e retornar uma lista com esses valores
static List<String> getValuesFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    List<String> valores = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String linha : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename))) {
        for (String valor : linha.split(",")) {
            valores.add(valor);
        }
    }
    return valores;
}

// ler valores de cada arquivo
List<String> valoresArq1 = getValuesFromFile("arq1.txt");
List<String> valoresArq2 = getValuesFromFile("arq2.txt");

// remover de arq1 todos os valores que estão em arq2
valoresArq1.removeAll(valoresArq2);

// escrever o resultado no arquivo arq3.txt (cada elemento da lista ficará em uma linha)
Files.write(Paths.get("arq3.txt"), valoresArq1, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Só isso. `removeAll` remove todos os elementos de `valoresArq2` que estão em `valoresArq1`. Não importa se há repetidos ou se algum valor de `arq2` não existe em `arq1`, o método já cuida de tudo isso.

---

Um ponto que não ficou claro é se os valores de `arq1` estão um em cada linha, ou se é possível ter linhas como `10,20,30` (já que você faz `split` em ambos os arquivos).

Nesse caso, se `arq1` tiver uma linha como `10,20,30` (e supondo que esses valores não estão em `arq2`), o resultado final terá os números 10, 20 e 30 separados, um em cada linha.

---

Sobre comparação de strings, [em Java deve-se usar `equals`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/112052) em vez dos operadores `==` e `!=`.