# Problema em comparar string em java

Tags: java

Sou novo no desenvolvimento usando java e me deparei com o seguinte erro:
Ao dar o return dentro do meu if que está dentro do for o java da o seguinte erro:"Missing return statement"
A grande questão é que eu preciso exatamente do meu índice que eu retorno dentro do if.

```
private int constructor(String key){
        String format = new FormatString().Format(key);
        for(int i = 0; i < this.keysOfMap.length; i++){

            for(int k = 0; k < this.valuesOfKey[i].length; k++){
                System.out.println(i);
                  if(format == this.valuesOfKey[i][k]){
                      return  i;
                  }
              }
        }
    };
```

Um outro problema é que não está caindo dentro do meu if, pois a comparação de string está retornando false mesmo ambos sendo a mesma coisa por ex:

```
    if("ola" == "ola")
        //true
    
    if(format == 'subtrair')
       //false
       //no meu format está chegando literalmente a palavra subtrair e mesmo assim ele retorna false;

    if(format == this.valuesOfKey[i][k])
       //false
       //aqui ele tbm retorna false, mesmo tendo dentro do meu array a palavra "subtrair"
      
      //eu usei o .getClass().getSimpleName() em ambos os valores sendo comparados e todos são do tipo String;
```

Realmente já não sei o que fazer, se puderem me dar um norte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Certo, vamos por partes.

Sobre o retorno, todo método do Java que declara um tipo de retorno deve possuir um retorno, neste caso este código abaixo só retorna algo se entrar dentro do for,
o Java compreende que se o this.keysOfMap.length for igual a 0 (ou seja se não houver elementos) ele não entra dentro do for e portanto não retorna valor.

```java
private int constructor(String key){
    String format = new FormatString().Format(key);
    for(int i = 0; i < this.keysOfMap.length; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < this.valuesOfKey[i].length; k++){
            System.out.println(i);
              if(format == this.valuesOfKey[i][k]){
                  return  i;
              }
          }
    }
};
```

Uma forma de arrumar isso é retornar um Optional ou retornar um tipo que aceita referencia como um Integer, por exemplo:

```java
private Integer constructor(String key){
    String format = new FormatString().Format(key);
    for(int i = 0; i < this.keysOfMap.length; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < this.valuesOfKey[i].length; k++){
            System.out.println(i);
              if(format == this.valuesOfKey[i][k]){
                  return  i;
              }
          }
    }
    return null;
};
```

Neste caso se this.keysOfMap não tiver elementos o método retorna nulo. Para isso foi necessário alterar o tipo de retorno de int para Integer, visto que int é um primitivo ele não pode ser nulo.

Sobre a comparação da String, strings no Java são objetos, quando você faz uma comparação como:

```java
String nome1 = "Rafael";
String nome2 = "Rafael";
System.out.print(nome1 == nome2)
```

O que está sendo comparado é se o objeto String nome1 é igual ao objeto String nome2.

Para comparar o conteúdo do objeto, ou seja as strings "Rafael" as instâncias da classe String tem alguns métodos como equals e equalsIgnoreCase;

```java
String nome1 = "Rafael";
String nome2 = "rafael";
nome1.equals(nome2); // false porque Rafael != rafael
nome1.equalsIgnoreCase(nome2); // true porque ignora maíusculas de minusculas na comparação.
```

Se você precisar comparar seus objetos pelos valores deles você pode implementar métodos como equals neles que fazem esta comparação.

É importante neste ponto também entender o que é ser igual, e o porque o Java faz isso.

Alguns "padrões de projeto" tem definições de igual diferentes.

O entity (entidade) compreende que dois objetos são o mesmo objeto se o identificador deles for igual, por exemplo, se você tem dois objetos e ambos tem um identificador chamado "id" e o valor deles é igual então pelo entity compreende-se que eles são o mesmo objeto.

Já no Value Object (objeto valor) compreende que um objeto é igual a outro quando todas as propriedades tem o mesmo valor.

Neste caso o que vale é a intenção (do código, o que o código quer/deve fazer), nem sempre objetos devem ser iguais porque tem o mesmo valor, e Java é uma das linguagens (como muitas outras) que permite este tipo de comportamento.

Comment: Bom dia ooredroxo, gostei bastante da sua resolvi e o erro do retorno, porem ainda continuo com erro em comparar as minhas strings

Comment: Tem algo que eu possa editar na minha pergunta para facilitar o seu auxilio ?

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado conseguir solucionar a minha questão

Answer (score 0):

em vez de:

```
if(format == 'subtrair')
```

use:

```
if(format.equalsIgnoreCase("subtrair"))
```

consulte esta pergunta para maiores detalhes:
[Como comparar Strings em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java)

Answer (score -1):

para o primeiro problema  onde tens o erro -> "Missing return statement" além de retorna o i dentro do if, no final do bloco antes de fechares o metodo também precisas retornar algum valor, nesse caso sugiro que faças um return -1

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite,

Estou no início do curso de Java, mas passei por esse caso a pouco tempo.

Quando se tenta comparar dois objetos em Java sem implementar o método equals, o retorno vai ser o mesmo que igualar dois objetos, pois o que será retornado é o endereço de memória daquele objeto e não seu conteúdo.

Para que seja comparado o conteúdo das strings precisa ser implementado o método equals antes de chamar a função.