# Problemas de repetição em uma estrutura while em Java

Tags: java, while

Esse código não esta funcionando corretamente. Quando entra a senha correta, o algoritmo continua perguntando a senha novamente, não sai da estrutura do `while`.

```
public class Dowhile {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the password: ");
        String password= sc.nextLine();
        
        while (password != "kayane") {
            System.out.println("Enter the right password: ");
            password= sc.nextLine();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to the platform!");
        
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/357

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como comparar Strings em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java)

Comment: Troca o while por -> while ("kayane".equals(password)) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você usa o operador "!=" para comparar string você na verdade está comparando o endereço onde ela esta armazenada e não o valor. Para comparar o valor deve-se usar o método equals:

```
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the password: ");
        String password = sc.nextLine();
        
        while (!password.equals("kayane") ) {
            System.out.println("Enter the right password: ");
            password = sc.nextLine();
            
        }
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to the platform!");
        
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

O método equals tem um retorno bolean então se for igual retorna true do contrario false. Por isso o "!"

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).