# Problemas com condicionais

Tags: java

Estou tentando criar um programa que diga para os alunos se dirigirem a secretaria ou não.
Porém ao digitar qualquer número diferente de 0 é exibida a mesma mensagem que deveria aparecer somente quando a pessoa digitar o número 0. Estou quebrando a cabeça aqui e não consegui achar onde errei em minha condicional.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String cpf = null;
  int resposta;
  cpf = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite seu CPF");
    resposta = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "O seu CPF " + cpf + " está correto?");
    
        if (resposta == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            
            if (resposta == 0){
            
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "VocÊ precisa procurar a secretaria ");
                
                if (resposta != 0) {
            
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voce não precisa procurar a secretaria");
            }

            } 
        } else {
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por gentileza, feche o programa e digite novamente o CPF ");

    }  
 }

}
```

Comment: Veja: [Como comparar Strings em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/357)

Comment: Só uma observação: [O StackOverflow não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-sopt-vers%c3%a3o-curta).

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que entendi da sua pergunta o problema está nas "}", note que no trecho abaixo as chaves referentes a segunda condicional, estão fechando somente após a terceira condicional.

```
if (resposta == 0){ 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "VocÊ precisa procurar a secretaria ");
if (resposta != 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voce não precisa procurar a secretaria");
}
}
```

O correto:

```
if (resposta == 0){ 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "VocÊ precisa procurar a secretaria ");
}
if (resposta != 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voce não precisa procurar a secretaria");
}
```